# Determine if all decimal digits are unique

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

[Deleted questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791278/write-a-function-that-takes-an-unsigned-integer-as-input-and-returns-true-if-al) sometimes make for great golf material.

Write a function that takes a nonnegative integer as input, and returns true if all the digits in the base 10 representation of that number are unique. Example:

```
48778584 -> false
17308459 -> true
```

Character count includes only the function.

If you choose to answer in C or C++: no macros, no undefined behaviour; implementation-defined behaviour and compiler warnings are fine.

Comment: I'd still be interested in other C or C++ solutions as per the question that inspired this one.

Comment: Why no C or C++ macros or undefined behavior? That's oddly limiting to just two languages.

Answer (score 31):

### Golfscript, <del>8</del> 7 characters:

```
{`..&=}
```

- `` ` `` - stringify the argument
- `..` - clone twice
- `&` - intersect with itself (remove duplicates)
- `=` - check for equality.

if the function needs to be named (**<del>10</del> 9 characters**):

```
{`..&=}:a
```

if a program suffices (**<del>5</del> 4 characters**):

```
..&=
```

Comment: The `$` is unnecessary, as `.&` preserves the order of the array elements.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen good catch, thanks

Comment: The hard part about challenges like this is being the first to see it.

Comment: @primo yet, somehow, they still get +6 score within half a day.

Comment: @JanDvorak Parkinson's law of triviality at work

Comment: @Claudiu You can understand the law. Realise you're being subjected to it. Then upvote the answer anyway.

Comment: Golfscript 'answers' are officially not funny any more.

Comment: @NathanChere what do you mean? [the last (and only) time that loophole was suggested](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1098/7209) it dropped to -3 before getting deleted by the suggester the next morning. If you don't like golfscript answers, don't upvote them.

Answer (score 26):

## Python 2 (28)  <strike>(32)</strike>

```
lambda n:10**len(set(`n`))>n
```

The backticks take the string representation. Converting to a set removes duplicates, and we check whether this decreases the length by comparing to 10^d, which is bigger than all d-digit number but no (d+1)-digit numbers.

Old code:

```
lambda n:len(set(`n`))==len(`n`)
```

Comment: Ha I had this *exact* same answer ready, just replace `n` with `i`

Comment: @Claudiu so did I. `f=lambda _:len(\`_\`)==len(set(\`_\`))`

Comment: Yeah, with these bite-size challenges, everyone is going to converge on pretty much the same thing. I was also trying `lambda n:max(map('n'.count,'n'))<2` (the single quotes are backticks), but it's two chars longer.

Comment: Never knew about backticks before!  Unfortunately it appears to be eliminated in Python 3: [What do backticks mean to the Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1673071/5987)

Answer (score 17):

### APL (6)

```
≡∘∪⍨∘⍕
```

One of the few times where tacit style is shorter in APL too.

It's 8 characters to give it a name,

```
f←≡∘∪⍨∘⍕
```

but that's not necessary to use it:

```
      ≡∘∪⍨∘⍕ 199
0
      ≡∘∪⍨∘⍕ 198
1
      f←≡∘∪⍨∘⍕
      f¨ 198 199 200 201
1 0 0 1
      ≡∘∪⍨∘⍕¨ 198 199 200 201
1 0 0 1
```

Comment: I think the second jot can be removed to make it 5. It would still be a valid function by itself (though it would require grouping parens to use it with each operator in the last example).

Answer (score 11):

## Perl, 19 characters

```
print<>!~/(\d).*\1/
```

Comment: assuming output can be treated as true and no-output can be treated as false, your logic is reversed. You should return true if there's no repetition.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sounds about right. I'll fix that.

Comment: Not-match operator: `<>!~/(\d).*\1/`.

Comment: @primo Thanks! So much to learn :)

Comment: The input is specified as being a non-negative integer, so I don't think you need to verify that. If you indeed don't, you can change `\d` to `.`.

Answer (score 9):

#### [Rebmμ](https://github.com/hostilefork/rebmu) (10 characters)

```
e? AtsAuqA
```

Rebmu's "mushing" trick is that it's case-insensitive, so characters are run together.  Whenever a case *transition* is hit, that splits to the next token.  By using transitions instead of a CamelCase kind of thing, the unique choice to start with a capital run means a "set-word" is made.  (While set-words can be used for other purposes in symbolic programming, they are evaluated as assignments by default).

So this "unmushes" to:

```
e? a: ts a uq a
```

The space is needed because once you've begun a series of runs of alternating cases, you can't use that trick to get a set-word after the first unless you begin a new run.  So `e?AtsAuqA` would have gotten you `e? a ts a uq a`...no assignment.

*(Note: For what may be no particularly good reason, I tend to prefer rethinking solutions so that there are no spaces, if character counts are equal.  Since brackets, parentheses, and strings implicitly end a symbol...there are often a fair number of opportunities for this.)*

In any case, when mapped to the Rebol that it abbreviates:

```
equal? a: to-string a unique a
```

Throwing in some parentheses to help get the gist of the evaluation order:

```
equal? (a: (to-string a)) (unique a)
```

So the prefix equality operator is applied to two arguments--the first the result of assigning to `a` of the string version of itself, and the second the result of `unique` being run against that string.  It so happens that unique will give you back the elements in the same order you passed them...so unique of "31214" is "3124" for instance.

Run it with:

```
>> rebmu/args "e? AtsAuqA" 17308459             
== true
```

There's also some stats and debug information:

```
>> rebmu/args/stats/debug "e? AtsAuqA" 48778584 
Original Rebmu string was: 10 characters.
Rebmu as mushed Rebol block molds to: 10 characters.
Unmushed Rebmu molds to: 15 characters.
Executing: [e? a: ts a uq a]
== false
```

If the requirement is that one must define a named/reusable function you can make an "A-function" which implicitly takes a parameter named a with `a|`.  (A B-function would be created with `b|` and take a parameter named A then one named B).  So that would add five more characters...let's say you call the function "f"

```
Fa|[e? AtsAugA]
```

*["You laugh!  They laughed at Einstein!  Or wait...did they?  I...don't know."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDKaz1iB9wQ)*

Comment: I used to think the language was pronounced like `Reb moo`, but now I'm not sure if it's supposed to be `Rebum mew` or `Reb mew` or something else.

Comment: After playing Nethack, I read `Fa|[e? AtsAugA]` as `False? SomeGibberish`

Comment: @Quincunx does `s` really decay to `[` in Nethack?

Comment: @JanDvorak I've seen some letters do decay into [ after some time

Comment: @Quincunx Just playing with the logo.  I think `REBmu` is probably better.  Either way, the beard is tight..it pinches.  Guess you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 7):

## FRACTRAN - <strike>53</strike> 38 fractions

```
47/10 3/5 106/47 3599/54272 53/61 2881/27136 2479/13568 2077/6784 1943/3392 1541/1696 1273/848 1139/424 871/212 737/106 469/53 142/3953 67/71 5/67 1/147 1/363 1/507 1/867 1/1083 1/1587 1/2523 1/2883 1/4107 1/5547 1/7 1/11 1/13 1/17 1/19 1/23 1/29 1/31 1/37 1/43
```

Uses division to count the number of occurrences of each digit. Call by putting n in register 2 and setting register 5 to 1, gives output in register 3 (0 if false, 1 if true). Also, make sure the rest of your program uses only registers > 71.

---

Edit 25/12/14: It's been 7 months and we've since gotten Stack Snippets, so here's one to test the code (using my could-be-better interpreter [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40285/21487)).

```js
var ITERS_PER_SEC=1E5;var TIMEOUT_MILLISECS=5E3;var ERROR_INPUT="Invalid input";var ERROR_PARSE="Parse error: ";var ERROR_TIMEOUT="Timeout";var ERROR_INTERRUPT="Interrupted by user";var running,instructions,registers,timeout,start_time,iterations;function clear_output(){document.getElementById("output").value="";document.getElementById("stderr").innerHTML=""};function stop(){running=false;document.getElementById("run").disabled=false;document.getElementById("stop").disabled=true;document.getElementById("clear").disabled=false}function interrupt(){error(ERROR_INTERRUPT)}function error(msg){document.getElementById("stderr").innerHTML=msg;stop()}function factorise(n){var factorisation={};var divisor=2;while(n>1){if(n%divisor==0){var power=0;while(n%divisor==0){n/=divisor;power+=1}if(power!=0)factorisation[divisor]=power}divisor+=1}return factorisation};function fact_accumulate(fact1,fact2){for(var reg in fact2)if(reg in fact1)fact1[reg]+=fact2[reg];else fact1[reg]=fact2[reg];return fact1};function exp_to_fact(expression){expression=expression.trim().split(/\s*\*\s*/);var factorisation={};for(var i=0;i<expression.length;++i){var term=expression[i].trim().split(/\s*\^\s*/);if(term.length>2)throw"error";term[0]=parseInt(term[0]);if(isNaN(term[0]))throw"error";if(term.length==2){term[1]=parseInt(term[1]);if(isNaN(term[1]))throw"error";}if(term[0]<=1)continue;var fact_term=factorise(term[0]);if(term.length==2)for(var reg in fact_term)fact_term[reg]*=term[1];factorisation=fact_accumulate(factorisation,fact_term)}return factorisation}function to_instruction(n,d){instruction=[];divisor=2;while(n>1||d>1){if(n%divisor==0||d%divisor==0){reg_offset=0;while(n%divisor==0){reg_offset+=1;n/=divisor}while(d%divisor==0){reg_offset-=1;d/=divisor}if(reg_offset!=0)instruction.push(Array(divisor,reg_offset))}divisor+=1}return instruction};function run(){clear_output();document.getElementById("run").disabled=true;document.getElementById("stop").disabled=false;document.getElementById("clear").disabled=true;timeout=document.getElementById("timeout").checked;var code=document.getElementById("code").value;var input=document.getElementById("input").value;instructions=[];code=code.trim().split(/[\s,]+/);for(i=0;i<code.length;++i){fraction=code[i];split_fraction=fraction.split("/");if(split_fraction.length!=2){error(ERROR_PARSE+fraction);return}numerator=parseInt(split_fraction[0]);denominator=parseInt(split_fraction[1]);if(isNaN(numerator)||isNaN(denominator)){error(ERROR_PARSE+fraction);return}instructions.push(to_instruction(numerator,denominator))}try{registers=exp_to_fact(input)}catch(err){error(ERROR_INPUT);return}running=true;iterations=0;start_time=Date.now();fractran_iter(1)};function regs_to_string(regs){reg_list=Object.keys(regs);reg_list.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});out_str=[];for(var i=0;i<reg_list.length;++i)if(regs[reg_list[i]]!=0)out_str.push(reg_list[i]+"^"+regs[reg_list[i]]);out_str=out_str.join(" * ");if(out_str=="")out_str="1";return out_str};function fractran_iter(niters){if(!running){stop();return}var iter_start_time=Date.now();for(var i=0;i<niters;++i){program_complete=true;for(var instr_ptr=0;instr_ptr<instructions.length;++instr_ptr){instruction=instructions[instr_ptr];perform_instr=true;for(var j=0;j<instruction.length;++j){var reg=instruction[j][0];var offset=instruction[j][1];if(registers[reg]==undefined)registers[reg]=0;if(offset<0&&registers[reg]<-offset){perform_instr=false;break}}if(perform_instr){for(var j=0;j<instruction.length;++j){var reg=instruction[j][0];var offset=instruction[j][1];registers[reg]+=offset}program_complete=false;break}}if(program_complete){document.getElementById("output").value+=regs_to_string(registers);stop();return}iterations++;if(timeout&&Date.now()-start_time>TIMEOUT_MILLISECS){error(ERROR_TIMEOUT);return}}setTimeout(function(){fractran_iter(ITERS_PER_SEC*(Date.now()-iter_start_time)/1E3)},0)};
```

```html
<div style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="float:left; width:50%;">Code:<br><textarea id="code" rows="4" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;width:90%;">47/10 3/5 106/47 3599/54272 53/61 2881/27136 2479/13568 2077/6784 1943/3392 1541/1696 1273/848 1139/424 871/212 737/106 469/53 142/3953 67/71 5/67 1/147 1/363 1/507 1/867 1/1083 1/1587 1/2523 1/2883 1/4107 1/5547 1/7 1/11 1/13 1/17 1/19 1/23 1/29 1/31 1/37 1/43</textarea><br>Input:<br><textarea id="input" rows="2" style="overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;width:90%;">2^142857 * 5</textarea><p>Timeout:<input id="timeout" type="checkbox" checked="true"></input></p></div><div style="float:left; width:50%;">Output:<br><textarea id="output" rows="6" style="overflow:scroll;width:90%;"></textarea><p><input id="run" type="button" value="Run" onclick="run()"></input><input id="stop" type="button" value="Stop" onclick="interrupt()" disabled="true"></input><input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear_output()"></input>&nbsp;<span id="stderr" style="color:red"></span></p></div></div>
```

Replace `142857` with another number. Output should be `3^1` if true, `1 = 3^0` if false. Takes a while for larger numbers (well, this *is* FRACTRAN...).

Comment: See [this answer](/a/246448) for a 15-fraction solution.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript - 23 Characters

As a function (ECMAScript 6):

```
f=x=>!/(.).*\1/.test(x)
```

Or taking input from a prompt (25 characters)

```
!/(.).*\1/.test(prompt())
```

Answer (score 6):

## C# <strike>73</strike> <strike>60</strike> 59

First golfing for me ...

> Write a **function** that takes a **nonnegative integer** as input

```cs
bool f(int i){return(i+"").Distinct().SequenceEqual(i+"");}
```

<strike>Could strip another character by converting `uint` to `int`, but I rather take the task too literally than the other way around.</strike>
Here we go ...

Comment: Some options: `i => (i + "").Distinct().SequenceEqual(i + "");`

Comment: @NPSF3000 Thanks! Edited my answer. I had something like this on my mind, but oh well ... I totally forgot about `+""` calling `ToString()` under the hood.

Comment: A more literal interpretation of "nonnegative integer" suggests that a signed integer will be passed in, but it will never be negative.

Comment: Well, I guess it will be ok then ...

Comment: Use C# 6 and you can use: bool f(int i)=>(i+"").Distinct().SequenceEqual(i+""); (53 bytes)

Comment: Some people claim you must count the characters in `using System.Linq;` as well.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Some, yes. Common practice on CG.SE seems to be that `using`s can be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 34 bytes

UB is only disallowed in C, huh?

```
'0.<".@|>i\re@..j..2'2#!>.(&,\,<.-
```

This works on x64, at least. Can't guarantee it'll work on other architectures.

Expects the number on STDIN, immediately followed by EOF (no trailing newline). Prints "0" (with trailing newline) iff the digits are unique.

Edit: there is now [an online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=17308459#%270.%3C%22.%40%7C%3Ei%5Cre%40..j..2%272%23!%3E.(%26%2C%5C%2C%3C.-). This code seems to work in wasm, too (but I still haven’t tested native ARM or other processors).

### High-level Overview

Roughly equivalent to this C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // A bitfield of the seen numbers:
    // e.g. if "12" is input, this is 0b0000'0000'0000'0110;
    // if "3" is input, this is 0b0000'0000'0000'1000; etc.
    int seen = 0;

    while (1) {
        // Get a number in. If EOF is read,
        // we haven't encountered a duplicate, so indicate success.
        int i = getchar();
        if (i == EOF) {
            puts("0");
            break;
        }

        // Check if the digit has already been seen.
        // If so, exit without printing anything.
        // If not, add this digit to the bitfield.
        i = 1 << (i - '0');
        if (i & seen) break;
        seen = seen | i;
    }
}
```

### How does Trilangle work?

Trilangle is a 2-D programming language laid out in a triangular grid (hence the name). The IP can move in one of six directions; it starts heading southwest. If it walks off the edge of the grid, it continues one row or diagonal to its left.

The memory model is like a stack, but it's possible to index into it.

### Explanation of the Code

The interpreter unfolds that code into this triangular grid:

```
       '
      0 .
     < " .
    @ | > i
   \ r e @ .
  . j . . 2 '
 2 # ! > . ( &
, \ , < . - . .
```

I hope this explanation makes any sense. Here goes nothing.

Below is an image of the code, with the IP's paths highlighted in various colors.

[image]

The IP starts on the red path, where it hits the following instructions:

- `'0`: Push the number 0 to the stack
- `<`: Change the direction of control flow
- `i`: Get a character from STDIN and push it to the stack; pushes -1 on EOF
- `>`: Branch on the sign of the top of the stack

If the value is negative, EOF was read, and the IP continues on the green path:

- `e`: Pop from the stack, and push `1 << value`. This is the UB: `1 << -1` is undefined. At least on x64, it evaluates to 0.
- `.`: No-op
- `!`: Print the top of the stack as a decimal integer
- `,`: Pop from the stack
- `i`: Attempt to read from STDIN again (always sees EOF on this path)
- `@`: End program

The `,i` aren't strictly necessary on this code path, but they're harmless to leave in.

If a character was successfully read, control flow continues on the blue path:

- `"0`: Push the value of the character '0' (i.e. 48) to the stack
- `-`: Pop two values from the stack and push their difference
- `..`: No-ops
- `e`: Pop from the stack and push `1 << value`
- `|`: Redirect control flow
- `".,`: Push the value of the character '.' and immediately pop it, effectively a no-op
- `2`: Duplicate the top of the stack
- `.`: Another no-op
- `\`: Redirect control flow
- `'2`: Push the number 2 to the stack
- `..`: Even more no-ops
- `j`: The indexing function. After this, the stack contains `{ seen, i, i, seen }` (from the C code above), in that order.
- `.`: Yet another no-op
- `&`: Pop two values from the stack and push `a & b` (bitwise and)
- `(`: Decrement the top of the stack. If `seen & i` is 0, the top of the stack is now negative; otherwise, it's still positive
- `.`: Yep, still a no-op
- `>`: Branch

If `i` and `seen` have any bits in common, the IP follows the yellow path; otherwise, the IP follows the magenta path.

The yellow path contains a harmless `r` (bitwise or) instruction, before the IP hits `@` and the program ends.

On the magenta path, the IP continues as follows:

- `<`: Redirect control flow
- `,`: Pop from the stack
- `\`: Redirect control flow
- `#`: Ignore the next instruction (`j`)
- `r`: Pop two values from the stack and push `a | b` (bitwise or)
- `|`: Redirect control flow
- `<`: Redirect control flow, merging with the red path

From which it reads the next character from STDIN, and continues until it either reads the same character twice or reads EOF.

### Disassembly

I recently added a `--disassemble` flag to the interpreter. The output is fairly straightforward if you understand the syntax:

```
0.0:    PSI #0
0.2:    GTC
0.3:    BNG 2.0
1.0:    PSC '0' ; 0x30
1.1:    SUB
1.4:    EXP
1.6:    PSC '.' ; 0x2e
1.7:    POP
1.8:    DUP
1.11:   PSI #2
1.14:   IDX
1.16:   AND
1.17:   DEC
1.19:   BNG 4.0
        JMP 3.0
2.0:    EXP
2.2:    PTI
2.3:    POP
2.4:    GTC
2.5:    EXT
3.1:    IOR
3.2:    EXT
4.1:    POP
4.4:    IOR
4.7:    JMP 0.2
```

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, <s>35</s> 25 characters

(27 if the function needs a name.)

```
Unequal@@IntegerDigits@#&
```

**EDIT:** Saved 8 characters thanks to belisarius!

Comment: `Unequal @@ IntegerDigits@# &` could do, I think

Comment: @belisarius oh nice, I was looking for something like that but couldn't find it (and didn't think that chained `≠` would compare non-adjacent elements). Thanks, that shortens this a lot!

Comment: You don't have to give it a name, right? `Unequal@@IntegerDigits@#&` is 25 characters.

Comment: @Akater true, I can't see a requirement for the name in the challenge. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby (24 bytes)

Use a regular expression to match "some character, followed by zero or more characters, then the same character".

```
->(s){!!(s !~/(.).*\1/)}
```

If truthy or falsy values are accepted, rather than literal `true` or `false`, then we get 20 characters:

```
->(s){s !~/(.).*\1/}
```

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249355/17216) by omitting the parentheses around the function parameter. Also, presumably your 20 byte version used to not return literal `true` / `false` in a previous version of Ruby, but in modern Ruby it does: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf106jWLO6WEGxTl9DT1NPK8ZQv/Z/eUZmTqpCnm16akkxF5DO0yvJj8@0VqiyTYsGs4tjuRQKSkuKFZSUq/NqrRSUqxUVq2oVbIGMKr3knMTi4loQs1aJKzUv5b@Jhbm5hamFCZehubGBhYmpJQA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## C (87)

Since I can't win, I'll go for efficiency.

Function code:

```
int u(uint32_t d){short s=0,f;while(d){f=1<<d%10;if(s&f)return 0;s|=f;d/=10;}return 1;}
```

Comment: Oh, and since I still can't comment on other people's posts -- I'd like to say that [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28378/21245) was a neat solution, even if inaccurate when it "overflows".

Comment: [70  bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/NToQwFIXX9ilqDaYkRSk/dsbScecTzNINgYIFvJi2uJmZVxc7YzK6O19yz3dym6SZaujX1bCBjbKjCzjTg24xxIduttSoQaUSJDwqnsaj4lUFEU/ZcFTmfmTmqEZptV8s3A7ytN4ZaKal1bhyvjXzw/sOoa/ZtMhr56kBH7zogG4@bcgdJZFocbLDkXsDwjAw3FGI8Qsme7togp8xea0np0ks0Qmh0EEftQF6Vl48Fy0vnkSWh5NfzLLA4o95WV6zEEUprrTlmzL718vzojgvrd9NN9W9W5PwhWo22x8)

Comment: Maybe you won't believe me, but `int` is shorter than `short` :)

Answer (score 5):

### R, <s>53</s> <s>51</s> <s>48</s> 34 Bytes

```
function(n)!grepl("(.).*\\1",n,,T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT1MxvSi1IEdDSUNPU08rJsZQSSdPRydE83@ahqGJmbmRsSZXmoaREZBpDmYampqCKHNzE1NzEMPS0MLUCKLG2NjERPM/AA)

<s>Convert to a string and split.  Convert to a table of counts minus 1, sum and negate</s>

<s>Inspired by [Most common number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42547/31347) answer by Alex and suggestion by Hugh.</s>

A couple saved, thanks to @plannapus
One more from @Gregor
And a couple from making it an anonymous function

Now with wonderful regex goodness thanks to @J.Doe.   This looks for any single char in the number that matches itself else where in the string.  The `grepl` command returns a logical that is then returned.  Perl style regexes is set to True.

Comment: You can also convert to string using `paste0` instead of `toString` and save 2 characters.

Comment: You can use `paste` instead of `paste0` to save one more character.

Comment: [45 bytes using utf8ToInt](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT1OxuDRXoyQxKSdVo7QkzSIk3zOvRKMgsbgkFSipqalrqPk/TcPQxMzcyFiTK03DyAjINAczDU1NQZS5uYmpOYhhaWhhaqT5HwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @J.Doe: even better ! :)

Comment: Used a different approach. [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jT1MxvSi1IEdDSUNPU08rJsZQSSdPx0AnRPN/moahiZm5kbEmV5qGkRGQaQ5mGpqagihzcxNTcxDD0tDC1AiixtjYxETzPwA "R – Try It Online") with regex.

Comment: @J.Doe The regex approach can be shorter: [29 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249355/17216). Or 24 bytes with R v4.1.0+.

Answer (score 4):

## J (9)

Assumes the value to be tested is in variable `b` <s>(I know this can be made into a function, but don't have a clue on *how*. J is confusing. Any help on this is appreciated)</s> Thanks Marinus!

```
(-:~.)@":
```

Checks if the lenght of the string rep of the number with all the duplicates removed is the same as the lenght of the regular string rep.

Comment: For a function you can do `(-:~.)@":`.

Comment: @marinus Oh wow, that's even shorter than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: HI, I found and posted a shorter J solution: 
-:~.&.":

Answer (score 4):

### R (<strike>70</strike>, <strike>60</strike>, <strike>53</strike>, 52)

Thank you all for the useful comments! Your comments are incorporated in the answer.

```
### Version 70 chars
f=function(x)!any(duplicated(strsplit(as.character(x),split="")[[1]]))

### Version 60 chars
f=function(x)all(table(strsplit(as.character(x),"")[[1]])<2)

### Version 53 chars
f=function(x)all(table(strsplit(paste(x),"")[[1]])<2)

### Version 52 chars
f=function(x)all(table(strsplit(c(x,""),"")[[1]])<2)

f(48778584)
f(17308459)
```

Comment: @plannapus, you are right. I got confused about "base 10 representation".

Comment: Using table and comparing against 0 instead of duplicated might save some characters

Comment: And I think you could leave the split parameter unnamed. I'm just on my phone so can't check easily but I believe it is the second parameter of strsplit so you could use positional instead of named arguments to save characters

Comment: And since you already take the first element of the result of `strsplit` why not coercing x to a character using `c(x,"")`? `f=function(x)all(table(strsplit(c(x,""),"")[[1]])<2)` is 1 character shorter :)

Answer (score 4):

## FRACTRAN, 15 fractions, 83 (or 32) bytes

This beats [Sp3000's 38-fraction solution](/a/28395).

$$\frac25,\frac{875}{88},\frac78,\frac{25{\cdot}17^c}{92},\frac14,\frac{15}{38},\frac{69}{2},\frac{23}{17},\frac{19}{3^b},\frac43,\frac{7}{23},\frac{26}{19},\frac{11}{7^c},\frac{1}{91},\frac{8}{11}$$

The initial state is \$3^n\cdot 13\cdot 23\$. It halts at \$1\$ if every digit in the base-\$b\$ representation of \$n\$ occurs fewer than \$c\$ times, and at some other value otherwise. Plug in \$b=10, c=2\$ to get the answer to the challenge as posed.

The final state is actually \$13^{k - \mathrm{wt}_c\left(\sum c^{d_i}\right)}\$, where \$d_1\cdots d_k\$ are the base-\$b\$ digits of \$n\$, and \$\mathrm{wt}_c\$ is the base-\$c\$ digit sum. Adding a power of \$c\$ increases the digit sum by \$1\$ if there is no carry, and doesn't increase it if there is a carry, so the final state is \$1\$ iff each digit occurs fewer than \$c\$ times.

The length of the \$b=10, c=2\$ version is 83 bytes in the decimal coding (`2/5,875/88,`...) that seems to be standard here. With a more efficient coding ([Elias δ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_delta_coding)), it's 32 bytes.

There's a fast online interpreter [here](https://pimlu.github.io/fractran/). I see no way to encode a program in the URL, so you'll have to copy-paste this:

```
2%5 875%88 7%8 25*17^2%92 1%4 15%38 69%2 23%17 19%3^10 4%3 7%23 26%19 11%7^2 1%91 8%11
```

Then enter, e.g., `[3,48778584],[13,1],[23,1]` as the input.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica (<del>20</del> 19)

(<del>22</del> 21 if function needs a name)

```
Max@DigitCount@#<2&
```

or

```
Max@DigitCount@#|1&
```

where | ist entered as [Esc]divides[Esc]

Comment: Nice. I forgot DigitCount existed, and wrote a solution based on conversion to strings. Yours is much better.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
((==)=<<nub).show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrzVZDw9ZW09bGJq80SVOvOCO//H9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagqGRscl/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1Hngv//Dc2NDSxMTC0B)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 22 bytes

```
s=>!s[new Set(s).size]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1k6xODovtVwhOLVEo1hTrzizKjX2f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RjSXkomFubmFqYWJko6Cvr5CWmJOcSqXkqG5sYGFiamlkgJIsKSoNJUrVi83sUAjTVPzPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## C99, 59 chars

```
a(x){int r=1,f[10]={};for(;x;x/=10)r&=!f[x%10]++;return r;}
```

Comment: C99 doesn't have implicit int, technically.

Comment: Not just "technically", it was specifically and intentionally removed. This is a syntax error in C99, and aside from a required diagnostic, syntax errors are in the same category as undefined behaviour (explicitly disallowed in the question): if an implementation accepts this, the standard makes no requirements whatsoever about the program's behaviour.

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/LTsMwEEXX@CsGo0iOmkCcB24xLju@oLvCwnKSEik4yHZQpJBfxzhFKuzu0cw9o1Gp6qU@eS/JFM@ddmBElrRHmr2KeeHtYAif@HQnaBabL9EepyiMNhtuGjcafW344m86rfqxbuDRurobbt/2CH0OXY1cYx1ZnTpGM7r6MCG3BEeshnQPkX3ROAGdgCQ6hifABzM2GB4AP8veNjjmaEEodNC77DRZlWfPWUvLe5YXYeUX8zww@2NaVZfMWFmxC@3otsr/9YqiLNdL/lu1vTxZn4YvhNrufgA)

Answer (score 2):

### Groovy (36 chars)

```
f={s="$it" as List;s==s.unique(!1)}
```

Tested it using:

```
println f(args[0].toInteger())
```

Comment: 'false' can be golfed via '1==0' or possibly something more clever. Good answer

Comment: @MichaelEaster `0>1` is shorter.

Comment: @ace Yes, though !1 works too...

Comment: @ace, MichaelEaster, thx for the help :-)

Comment: @WillP as suggested by MichaelEaster, use `!1` instead.

Comment: @ace, my mistake, thanks again, you both!

Answer (score 2):

## C, 58 bytes

```
f;a(x){for(f=0;x;x/=10)f+=1<<x%10*3;return!(f&920350134);}
```

Can keep a tally of up to 7 identical digits before rolling over.

**in test program** (it's easier to see how it works with the constant in octal)

```
a(x){int f=0;for(;x;x/=10)f+=1<<x%10*3;return!(f&06666666666);}

main(){
scanf("%d",&r);
printf("%o\n",a(r));}
```

If you happen to have a large power of 2 handy the constant can be calculated like `f&(1<<30)/7*6`

Comment: I think the comment by @xfix was intended for my post instead of yours? You didn't actually used `int main(int)` in your answer...

Comment: Having external information that doesn't count towards the code byte/char count is obviously not allowed. I suggest you remove the first version (53 bytes).

Comment: Please see my comment in the *edit summary*.

Comment: I voted to reject the edit, but I agree that the counts look wrong. I make them 67 and 63 (61).

Comment: My edit was rejected by other users. Please re-evaluate it.

Comment: @2501 Back in 2014 we were still thrashing out the rules here and cheeky answers were common. You're right my original answer wouldn't be acceptable now, so I've accepted your version of the code. I have however kept the info about how it works - this site has always been about sharing ideas and I think code should always come with an explanation (not just a score.) I see what you were trying to do but I also agree with the rejection. I'd forgotten this answer - thanks for highlighting. But it would have been better to leave a comment. See  https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1615/15599

Comment: I agree. If the random generator generates more than 7 identical digits in a row it produces a false positive?

Comment: @2501 yes, if there are eight 1's it will roll over and be indistinguishable from one 2. There's only so much info that can be stored in a single int. With larger variables you could use the constant `(1<<40)/15*14` instead of `(1<<30)/7*6` for up to 15 identical digits, or` (1<<50)/31*30`. for upto 31 identical digits.  It's a fault of the question that it doesn't say what the largest input you can expect is.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <s>66</s> 65 characters

```
f=function(x)!sum(duplicated((x%%10^(i<-1:nchar(x)))%/%10^(i-1)))
```

Separate the digits using integer division and modulo, then check if they are duplicates.

Usage:

```
> f(48778584)
[1] FALSE
> f(17308459)
[1] TRUE
```

Or, as @MickyT suggested, for 63 characters:

```
f=function(x)!anyDuplicated((x%%10^(i<-1:nchar(x)))%/%10^(i-1))
```

Comment: You could use `anyDuplicated` rather than `sum` and `duplicated` for 2 more

Answer (score 2):

### POSIX sh and egrep (<strike>47</strike>, <strike>43</strike>, 40)

```
f()([ ! `echo $1|egrep '([0-9]).*\1'` ])
```

- **[-1 char]:** Use `!` instead of `-z` with `test` - Thanks DigitalTrauma
- **[-1 char]:** Use `` `CODE` `` instead of `$(CODE)` - Thanks DigitalTrauma
- **[-2 chars]:** Use `fold -1` instead of `grep -o .`<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup> - Thanks DigitalTrauma.
- **[-3 chars]:** Check for repeated digits with a backreferenced regular expression.

If POSIX compliance is not important `echo PARAM |` can be replaced by `<<<PARAM`, reducing the functions length to **37**:

```
f()([ ! `egrep '([0-9]).*\1'<<<$1` ])
```

Usage:

```
$ if f 48778584; then echo true; else echo false; fi
false
$ if f 17308459; then echo true; else echo false; fi
true
```

---

<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup> <sub><sup>The `fold -N` notation is deprecated in some versions of `fold`.</sup></sub>

Comment: `f()(! [ \`fold -1<<<$1|sort|uniq -d\` ])` down to 38 by my count

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Good stuff thanks for sharing. I find that the tested command must be quoted, otherwise `test` croaks on it when `uniq -d` returns more than one line. So the shortest non-POSIX version is 40 characters. I know about the `[ !` notation, but I am suprised that `! [` also works, do you know why that is?

Comment: Ah I was using bash.  So I guess its longer if you want POSIX conformance.

Answer (score 2):

**Haskell:**

```
 import Data.List

 all ((== 1) . length) . group . sort . show
```

Comment: A little late to the party, but since you're importing `Data.List` anyway I'd suggest `nub`, which removes duplicates from a List. `(\x->nub x==x).show`

Comment: You didnt use pl... `main = interact $ show . ap (==) nub . show`

Answer (score 2):

## Java ( <s>131</s> <s>59</s> 57)

### 57 characters:

removed ^ and $ as @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ suggested

```
boolean u(int n){return !(n+"").matches(".*(.).*\\1.*");}
```

### 59 characters (works also with negative numbers!):

```
boolean u(int n){return !(n+"").matches("^.*(.).*\\1.*$");}
```

### <s>79</s> 78 characters (thanks @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ ):

Use for loop to save a few charachers and use int as a boolean array.

Use & instead of && to save 1 character (It turns out that java allows it).

```
boolean u(int n){for(int x=0;n>0&(x>>n%10&1)==0;n/=10)x|=1<<n%10;return n==0;}
```

### 131 characters (returns true for negative numbers):

```
boolean u(int n){int[] p=new int[]{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,32,29};double a=9001312320D;while(n>0){a/=p[n%10];n/=10;}return (long)a==a;}
```

with comments:

```
boolean unique(int n){
    int[] p=new int[]{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,32,29};//list of 10 first primes
    double a=9001312320D;//10 first primes multiplied
    while(n>0){
        a/=p[n%10];//divide by (n%10+1)th prime
        n/=10;//divide n by 10, next digit
    }
    return (long)a==a;//if a is integer then n has all digits unique
}
```

And answer that is technically correct (character count includes only the function, not global variables), but I think it's cheating, 29 characters:

```
boolean u(int i){return m[i];}
```

m[] is boolean array that contains correct answers for all 32-bit integers.

Comment: `"^.*(.).*\\1.*$"` You can drop `^` and `$`. They are implied by `matches()`

Comment: The 2nd approach can be done by using 10 bits in an int as a boolean array, which will eliminate the need for the prime table.

Comment: I know it's been three years, but if you remove the space between `return!` in the shortest answer, you can get to 56 bytes.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249319/17216)

Answer (score 2):

## J (8)

Competely sepertae from my previous answer.

```
*/@~:@":
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
-:~.&.":
```

Explanation:

```
         ": - converts the integer to a string
       &.   - "under" conjuction - uses the result from ": as operand to ~.
               then applies the inverse to the result, so converts the string back to integer
    ~.      - removes duplicates
  -:        - matches the operands
```

So, it first converts the number to a string, removes the duplicates and converts the resulting string to a number. Then the original number is matched against the transformed one.
In fact it is a hook of two verbs: `-:` and `~.&.":`

```
┌──┬──────────┐
│-:│┌──┬──┬──┐│
│  ││~.│&.│":││
│  │└──┴──┴──┘│
└──┴──────────┘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT9eqTk9NT8nqf2pyRr5CmoKpmbmJJReUY2hkbAIS@A8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 7 bytes

```
L,BDdq=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx8klpdD2v0pOYm5SSqKCoZ09lz8XCu//fxMLc3MLUwuT/4bmxgYWJqaWAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

the best I could come up with was the same as [one of the top voted answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28365/98541)

```julia
n->10^length(Set("$n"))>n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/T9fO0CAuJzUvvSRDIzi1RENJJU9JU9Mu739JanFJsYKtQrSJhbm5hamFiY6CobmxgYWJqSWQpaMAIg10FIyMQRJGxqYmZuYWlgZgtompYSxXQVFmXklOnp4GxCA9WzuFNChHU/M/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṡ`, 3 bytes

```
U∑=
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%A0&code=U%E2%88%91%3D&inputs=12345&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
Þu
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiw551IiwiIiwiNDg3Nzg1ODRcbjE3MzA4NDU5Il0=)

Answer (score 1):

## k4 (8)

```
  {x=.?$x}48778584
0b
  {x=.?$x}17308459
1b
```

inspired by a combination of the J and Golfscript answers

Answer (score 1):

### C, 76

This is no where near winning, but I'll post it anyway just to show an alternative approach.

```c
c;i;a[99];main(){while(~(c=getchar()))a[c]++;for(;i<99;)a[i++]>1&&puts("");}
```

Prints a new line if false, prints nothing if true.

Comment: This program has an undefined behavior. The correct signatures for main are `int main(int, char **)` or `int main(void)`. `int main(int)` is not valid.

Comment: @xfix I assume `main()` is ok then?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. It means the same thing as `main(void)` (when used in definition, in declaration it declares a function with unknown parameter list).

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript 73 chars**

```
function f(n){return !~(n+'').split('').sort().join('').search(/(\d)\1/)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge 98, 17 bytes

*This is a non-competing answer because Befunge does not have functions.*

```
~:1g1`j@1\1p3j@.1
```

Prints a `1` if the number's digits are all unique; otherwise, it just ends.

This works by accessing a cell in the Funge space whose `x` coordinate is the ASCII value of the character inputted (takes input character by character) and whose `y` coordinate is `1`. If the digit has not been seen before, the value of the cell is `32` (space character). If that is so, I set the value to 1.

As a bonus, this works for non-numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell - 26

```
!($args|sls '(.)(?=.*\1)')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6 (19 bytes)

```
{.comb.uniq==.comb}
```

`.comb` splits a string into characters (for example, `42.comb` gives `"4", "2"`). `.uniq` removes all non-unique characters. `.comb` characters in string (originally I used `.chars`, but `.comb` is shorter). `==` converts lists into number of elements in it, and compares the numbers. When `.` is used without object before, `$_` which is default function parameter is assumed. `{}` are function literals.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7  <s>114</s>  106 bytes

First golf, and this is no way going to win :P

```
def d(a):
    f=[];
    for i in str(a):
        if i in f:return False
        f.append(i)
    return True
```

Kinda want to see how other people would improve this :)

EDIT: With ProgramFOX's comments:

```
def d(a):
    f=[];
    for i in str(a):
        if i in f:return 1<0
        f+=[i];
    return 0<1
```

Comment: `return True` can be shortened to something like `0<1`. And `f.append(i)` can be shortened to `f+=[i]`.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, you can save one more character by dropping the `;` after `f+=[i]`. It is not necessary there.

Comment: Ugh... Too much php :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 40

```
f=lambda x:len(str(x))==len(set(str(x)))
```

The built-in `set` removes the duplicates, so if the length of a thing and the length of his set are equal, the thing does not have repeated elements.

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque, 2 bytes

Using the Unique built-in:

```
blsq ) 17308459U_
1
blsq ) 48778584U_
0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 138 bytes

Bad language choice.

run it like `uniqchars 112345678`

```golang
package main
import(."fmt"
."os"
."strings")
func main(){s:=Args[1]
f:=true
for _,e:=range s{if Count(s,string(e))>1{f=false}}
Println(f)}
```

Comment: This is post 65536 on the site! That's `2^16`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 bytes

```
n->d=digits(n);#d==#Set(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P1y7FNiUzPbOkWCNP01o5xdZWOTi1RCNF839BUWZeiUaahomFubmFqYWJpiYXTMjQ3NjAwsTUUlPzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>5</s> <s>3</s> 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a string.

```
¶â
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=tuI&input=IjE3MzA4NDU5Ig)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 29 bytes

```
lambda x:10**len({*str(x)})>x
```

Inspired on [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28365/82577) in Python 2; for Python 3 to only lag behind 2 by one byte is pretty rare :)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 28 bytes

```cs
i=>(i+"").ToDictionary(c=>c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy9CsIwFEb3PsUlOKT4g2Kl1ZqC4OgoOIhDDAleKAkkqVJCnr3G1uFbznc4wi2Fw@EkPBp9RO0bUMAGZA3FOSH56mrOOJ7c9lSwRuRDnWXKWMnFC@ibW0BADVp@7o9QVGVZ7apisSm366rY7WMOIQN4GtOCla5rPfO2k3Vi3vbjB6Ao5j8SQXCfqhP964q3bvRj2s2ilxfUks5IwHiAMFmRpEAcvg)

This lambda uses [presence or absence of an exception](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/8340) to determine whether a number has unique digits. If a digit occurs more than once, a duplicate key exception will be thrown when converting the string to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 12 bytes

```
dlMulMve1:0|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/Jce3NMe3LNXQyqDm////JoaWFuZGAA)

#### Explanation

```
dlMulMve1:0|  Implicit input from args

d             Split into digits
 lM           Push length of stack to next stack
   u          Keep only first occurrence of each unique digit
    lM        Push length of stack to next stack
      v       Switch to next stack
       e      If top 2 items are equal
        1      - Push 1
         :    Else
          0    - Push 0
           |  EndIf

              Implicit output of top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 11 bytes

```
FC 51 AC 8B FE F2 AE 59 E0 F7 C3
```

Listing:

```
    SEARCH:
FC      CLD                 ; string direction forward
51      PUSH CX             ; save loop counter 
AC      LODSB               ; load next digit from SI into AL, advance SI 
8B FE   MOV  DI, SI         ; DI is offset of next digit 
F2/ AE  REPNZ SCASB         ; search until match, ZF=1 if found 
59      POP  CX             ; restore loop counter 
E0 F7   LOOPNZ SEARCH       ; loop until match found or CX is 0
C3      RET                 ; return to caller
        ENDM
```

Callable function, input as digit array at `DS:SI`, length in `CX`.  Output `ZF=0` if unique, `ZF=1` if not unique.

Test program in IBM PC DOS that reads input from command line args, displays `T` or `F`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 12 bytes

```perl6
{!/(.).*$0/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WlFfQ09TT0vFQL/2f3FipUKahomRiYWxpjUXjGeKzDNBMDWt/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
DQƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//RFHGkf/Dh@KCrCDFkuG5mP//NDg3Nzg1ODQsIDE3MzA4NDU5)

### How it works

```
DQƑ - Main link. Takes n on the left
D   - Convert to digits
  Ƒ - Is it unchanged under:
 Q  -   Deduplication?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
S=ud
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X@wbWnK////ow2NjE1MdQx0wLSJaSwA)

```
S           # Hook: S fgx means f x(gx)
 =          # are they equal:
            # x (implied by S)
            # and
  u         # unique elements of x
   d        # when x is the decimal digits of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
q{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v7D6/38lEwtzcwtTCxMlAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, <s>28</s> 24 bytes

If output is 0, the digits are unique. Otherwise, there are dupes

```bash
<<<$[$#1-${#${(us::)1}}]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGJVpF2VBXpVpZpVqjtNjKStOwtjb2////JqZm5hbGRoYGlpYA)
<sub><s>[28 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/yVZDpVqjtNjKStOwVpPLxsZGJVpF2VBXRTkp9v///yamZuYWxkaGBpaWAA)</s></sub>

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript <sub><sup>/ Perl / PCRE / Python / .NET</sup></sub>), <s>66</s> 61 bytes

```
^(?!((?=(x{10})*(x*))(^|(?=(x*)(\5{9}x*))\6)+){2}\B\2*\3$)|^$
```

Takes its input in unary, as the length of a string of `x`s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9RT8IwFEb/CiwE7t3c2KaSSC0kJj74woM@OkkaKF21dE1bYLLtt08wMfH1nC/5cj7ZkbmNlcbHzsgtt/tKf/Hv3lLNT4NXLp5rA3Cmi2nYr2E5BFhSqJss7TCEOkSEdfuLQoTivnnorqyYYYRN3hVPRR4WtyNs16M@nJ4x8dWbt1ILwMQpueEwu4nvEImjKTmVUnEARS1nWyU1B8Qh1QelsBFUJc4o6WEST5DIHYCmIlFcC1/iIm9b6VZsBZIaZh1/0R7Ee/qB@Cf4f6EX2TKbXzX60lan4EUfmZLbgWVa8PkgiBTZVRaIfKScyCjCy2FQB4nlhjMPEpM985sSLGLjxmNzSfJwrciIOXjn7WVCuq5P4yxP0x8) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fS8MwFMW/Shxhze1amlYnaJp1k@3VJ9/MGqasEIhbTSpUsvjVa1oHvlzu@d0/57RHo5fDxzfChiGnz@8HjXDGguTldvOyWXnUnA3BllNWrhg4pJqgwLVGnTo0E6cZ82ituW216kiURon9erNdOJFJmic5HD/Hpeqf0sDhEUtg4y8bHA9mrcsC3Fq/5nseKt2zq6@6SqxKPo1Dt1iAUw0iJOoj1KOwBID4D8qwycBhO59P4aZsIXjO/rJixbz3Uu6et1IONaluCKk46V1OPcSkjwFIfZlQDEQs3YMfmbiH4Fd48SSKWNxiuNR4GGha3FH6Cw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNa@MwEL3nV6hC4BnHSWz3i6CYwLJbKCx7aHurGuG6Sm3WkYWsQsDxb8@Ow5560DDzZt57o3G1O2@2rnZMeFYwvuJsyZw3n9ob15aVgWi1jLda12UbdNUdXNMar0ChVE@rPkpYRG9PoP4004ANxoYetH54/P1La0xYhiRJwnLW2Eb3JgB3lTfL97L6GzwF3TaHJvCE8Zt8fbO@u8/XtxzlbN95EE2RStEWe1Lv4fnl5@MflDiwZg@ife2Db42lDBfZW1FwZTnScP/1Th2CkzRZZDjxzdG13YcBvuAJjUviV92XDRN3kxPplQQopm9yxtjF2f6vhd0Ulz5l8zmSNYPLhQ5lqGoQPiGz6VymDBAdo0RYRGTDtGKDpqq7aS/J6CuZZFPNhJUj2YzfzgoozzvYXgFsCzgOWTpiDMcYEXanCxQjqNthPU6YusM5Dvmofqg8VtcCTztxPqeL/DpN/wE) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LasMwEEX3/oqpyGLGsY3k0ELtikB/ww8IrdKoqLKRVOrg@NvdyKW74R7uuTNew2Wwh1V/jYML4K8@cyr79IOtwUnHGFt7PD4gHiVOs@ALpTilRNjftiglbB/n5yVm7RPtaS6X9rUt0/awo1u/W@@GRlS56GrQkifnwYEBbeNS4cO7tlUCRprCj0YHZDmjBPQZjLJo6KWswDSik6bhXQKxbGPZneyHQm0DRkDZ3yU62gu6@6LAqcKrk3u7oMuATSy1G4lIVzC6WKEtkKL@/2b4DsWP00GhDw4t0cpzUXL@Cw) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/taoMwGIVvxckLvtGlRMcKrYSW7feuwA8Ql85AlkhMUWpz7U47xn4@D4fDOb0ZhR06odQClhdWfImpOh61GPEcLTWenhBPHKc5ZZ7EOMWEYH1/qJhg@Tof/ObKPUnInPnyrczi8gXIvYYlOj@H7@a7l0p8hiSHG2f5xVjRtB2CCqQOQOr@6sgMDQdFh15JF9IwlxeEZteaq3ZUuSDbAgmHpmCVXwsQNC@kdtXD5KCpEn@cbpysW7YOu/toXNuJAaMpikGTX30j82ilE7Qzg/PrrDT/54Bqs75XUosAtPd@YTTNGPsB) - .NET

This regex apparently does not work in Java, Boost, or Ruby. The reasons are unknown as of yet.

```
^                          # tail = N = input number
(?!                        # Assert that there is no way for the below to match
    (
        (?=
            (x{10})*(x*)   # \2 = 10; \3 = tail % 10
        )
        (
            ^              # Allow the loop to iterate once without doing
                           # anything iff this is the first iteration of the
                           # main loop.
        |
            (?=
                (x*)       # \5 = floor(tail / 10)
                (\5{9}x*)  # \6 = tool to make tail = \5
            )\6            # tail = \5
        )+                 # Execute the above loop an arbitrary positive
                           # number of times.
    ){2}                   # Execute the above loop exactly twice, so that \3
                           # will contain the value it had at the beginning of
                           # the loop's second iteration.

    \B                     # Assert that we aren't at the beginning or end, or
                           # that N==0; the latter "or" part is undesirable,
                           # because it prevents this main algorithm from being
                           # able to match N==0, but even still, using "(?!^|$)"
                           # would be longer than "\B" and "|^$" combined.
    # Note that if (x{10})* repeated zero times, \2 will be a non-participating
    # capture group (unset). In ECMAScript this means it will behave as if \2=0.
    # In all other flavors, it means \2* will only be able to repeat zero times,
    # because \2 alone won't match anything. But this doesn't matter, since if
    # it was only able to match zero times before, it wouldn't be able to match
    # more than zero times now, anyway.
    \2*\3$                 # Assert tail % 10 != \3
)
|^$                        # Match N==0, which the main algorithm above can't.
```

See also my [decimal regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249355/17216). I feel that this unary version is more interesting, especially since unary is like a native integer data format for regex, whereas decimal is like passing an integer as a string, but it's definitely worth presenting decimal versions as well.

Comment: Wouldn't something naive like `^(?!0.*0|...|9.*9)` be shorter? Haven't thought hard about this and obviously you have, so probably I'm missing something.

Comment: @Thomas You're thinking of a regex that takes its input in *decimal* format. My regex takes it in unary, which is like a native integer format for regex. I have, however, now made a [separate post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249355/17216) taking decimal input.

Comment: Ahhhhh sorry I missed that. That is next level voodoo for sure!

Answer (score 1):

See also my [unary regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249319/17216). Although [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28363/17216) [posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28391/17216) [have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28402/17216) [already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31789/17216) [used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42635/17216) [a regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183150/17216) that take decimal input, this post provides a unified presentation, and outgolfs some of the previous posts (including a language in which there wasn't previously any regex post).

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 13 bytes

```
^(?!(.)+.*\1)
```

Takes its input in decimal. Returns a match for numbers with all-unique digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc87c8IwEATgv2Io4M6OjU0yKVAEVQoaiqTMY0ZjH/IlQtZIAhIev92BIjO0@xW7@6V2KtSeXcyD44b8prPf9Nt7aWmfvJB@/nEABzmfpP0nLAZQYFak7xX26eSARexeo2erAYtguCZ4vMsfEEWQpdi3bAjASE@qMWwJEAfSbo3Bo5amCM5whHE@RsFrACt1Ycjq2OJ8ejpxWKkVsHTKB1raCPqt/ED8B7oFO68W1ezKGFvf7YdLu1OGm8Qrq2mWDDMj1p0HwU@SBGcZXgr5dvxGxboFj3gMo5G7hBGuJyrhtjFED4zifO7LfHpfln8)

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 7 bytes

```
(.).*\1
```

Takes its input in decimal. Returns a non-match for numbers with all-unique digits.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc8/V8IwFAXwrwIM8F5rS4seB2Lq5MDCoKM65LSP9GlIc5JAlT@fvcLgOaz3N9x7v9Rehdqzi1lw3JDfdvabfgcvLfWjV9IvPw7gIKt5MkCOefJRDsn8gHns3qJnqwHzYLgmeLzLHhBFkIXoWzYEYKQn1Ri2BIhjaXfG4FFLkwdnOMIsm6HgDYCVOjdkdWyxWpxOHNZqDSyd8oFWNoJ@Lz4R/4FuwVblc7m8MsbWd/1kZffKcDPyympajiapEZvOg@AnSYLTFC@FY75dv1WxbsEjHsN06i5hhOuLUrhdDNEDozifhyJb3BfFHw)

#### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## [R](https://www.r-project.org) v3.5.2, 29 bytes

```
pryr::f(!grepl('(.).*\\1',n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xbsMwDEX3noL1YrKIAzvdrOoG3TvYHoxGcgkQikCqQxPk7K61/YeHh697/Oj2rH86jhFfNw1ZsMUznd/meWhPiWg33zu4@8gSsLFy5dSQg3hTFOAE9puzBrOvVROnzVDDev3kFAzvRPR4ARDwYEUtCxeUEzRdQ9M0LIsDjoAS0lZ@UMj7gUCmy@LlsEdYT7ieVB6roaPAiEwEj2MZfa8F2zm15MwPDioyPZ97313e@/4f)

Uses the same regex as [MickyT's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42635/17216), but `,,T` is unnecessary (the regex doesn't need to run in PCRE mode) and omitting it saves 3 bytes. Using `pryr`'s lambda syntax saves another 2 bytes.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org) v4.1.0+, 24 bytes

```
\(n)!grepl('(.).*\\1',n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=JY4xasNAEEX7nGKiRjPBMpLThCx7A_cuJBXC3lUGho3YWTc2PokbO5DcIJCr5DbWou4_Hp__r_d4-_L2-5h89fbXYaDnMbpJsMQ1rV-6rilXgRb9_6u2NnCynsVhoenAoSAD_jOiAAfQ4zRFp7obYuAwKkY3HLYcnOKJiM5PAAIWNEWdhBPKCoqqoLZt-t4Ae0BxYUwfKGRtQyDtprcy27mYRziPZH7PhuYGemQiOM9JaT8kLLtQklHbGMjIdLks528_dbV5reuFHg)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```
fn($n)=>!preg_match('/(.).*\1/',$n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU@7DsIwDNz5ClNFIoYWUhjTwMLCwgIbIAQloZVCGvUhIaF@e3EQi@Xz3flsX/gh2/jCAzNqMI4zh2o99rV@Xl@3Ni/4ZMHnOJ@e08UkJnKQI1PVnJVKSGaVeeq24YfjdrdHiR8oDWf21LS11bTLYpJelIrOLkISN92dGBrHIk5SDH799rZ6aB4lUUxySf686lwbvNmSTCdaQFVc5Ajgl@z@mLlM/XjqZjOkaODMhAcQPuGOEnVeVCFcAt2bSggYmJN9P4hkuRLiCw)

## Java, 33 bytes

```
n->!(n+"").matches("(.)+.*\\1.*")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNT@MwEL3zK4ZIqHY/rARuuAGxh5WQWC49tjmY4DQu7iSyJ/RjxW8vk7bsHsCX0Zv3/PTerMy7maxe3w5u3TaBYMVYdeS8qjosyTWohhq@kUN9UXoTI/wxDuHvBUDbvXhXQiRDPN4b9wpr5sSMgsPlvAATllEepQC/z97TRyS7tGH8q2m8NXgHFeQHnNxdChwliVRrQ2Vto0iEkiM1XCwyNUzkQbPLy@kL7PPK@Gg1zEqDaAM4bDuCHNBuvnZitotk18qh1LCpnbcgjjJVm/hstyTkV7RTXvAOLXucRMiKJ14I/v2vj2e6V6nYekcimSTMOiTAlJlzMdWaEC0D4edpIceA2Y@k8haXVE@v4R56JdzyyAp2LGsT5sX23OeIMCs0PIRgdlFVznuxHQ@2A6mP@asm9N04Ro6pBpzmmPEYjbigq0BUyrSt3wmUkrHYy/NpGu65CY6sGCyQzfY5ha6/6n@65eZUieQqJlxE6o/@HdLJ9U2afgI)

This uses a regex 1 byte shorter than [barteks2x's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31789/17216).

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

```
sub{pop!~/(.).*\1/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7RTsMwDPyVMEVbsrVbMrQX3Iw@wCs/wKaqmxpkyXQh6YRQFH69pBOIF/t89t3ZdZ524zV0LAwezwOwCX@2vsf@LQB7/2LcmjFcT9Fd3N33RqzlennQmzSCvXgx7YNRMHUy1R5kzLAmExzhIBblosja7C04FaUutOw@Zod@9vjPqszLB04SGFoRzi21vqZqK2NNr/poclVHSOwvDn8ZjpW5XWS0WsmIlgluy73gKGXkYT53HvthSoP8o4bbmPWQUmqa55enphlVub1X6gc)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```
->n{n.to_s !~/(.).*\1/}
```

Takes an integer as input. Returns a native boolean, true if the digits are unique.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7dCoMwDIXv9xTRG9tBY3WXrnsRlcGYP4USRStjjO3VXSqbFwnJyfkOmZbbc23Nqi70IvTDdYbokwqUeKyy9L1aowt49NY14EzX@PkAYFtwpcpqY@KK4oIPrtSIKq8LaOjODlZwHp31IlGJ/CHoGup8L@Q5Z6ZknrEdaYcJCCxBEMMjVmRaIgbjvrJvy2pLYpAHG4X/xsXPWw5rJuN9suSB/tGhc61a5Setvw)

### [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```
->s{s !~/(.).*\1/}
```

Takes a string as input. Returns a native boolean, true if the digits are unique.

This is identical to [John Feminella's 20 byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28402/17216) except for removing the unnecessary parentheses surrounding the function parameter, saving 2 bytes.

#### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 12 bytes

```
A`(.).*\1
^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYgxDoAwCAB3/mFSHRooYGF08hPG1MHBxcH4f6zDJXf3nO91HxRDWlssLeUxTxvBniPEajU1AaqMJupA0EEo3F9hlbma46@iBKI9uRC6fw)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 37 bytes

```
<?=!preg_match('/(.).*\1/',$argv[1]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WsaAoNT0@N7EkOUNDXV9DT1NPK8ZQX11HJbEovSzaMFbT@v///4bmxgYWJqaWAA)

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 16 bytes

```
say<>!~/(.).*\1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctLCsIwFAXQ@d1FZ4lgmvvS9APiDrqDThyktFBMaQUR0aX77PTAWdO2RH1O85JMkfJorH3rfntdrsW3NM6608BSP@pBCAIqRNRo0KIDDyQoYAArMII12IAt2EE85DgCCb@8PuZ83/XcR@fp/w)

This uses a regex 1 byte shorter than [Tal's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28363/17216). Another 2 bytes are saved by using `say` (requiring Perl v5.010+) instead of `print`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 21 bytes

```
$=>[=unique<=digits&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?F9L5oY)

-1 byte from abusing Arturo's hidden stack features. >:)

-5 bytes from using a tacit function and using the dup operator over the function.

Checks whether the list of digits of the input number is equal to itself when uniquified.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
{(#t)=#?t:$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWUC7RtFW2L7FSqajl4kqLNrEwN7cwtTCJVdBX0LVTSEvMKU4FChuaGxtYmJhaQoVLikpTAel8D9s=)

I think there's a way this one could be a train...

Explanation:

```
{(#t)=#?t:$x}  Main function. x is input
          $x   Convert x to string
        t:     Assign it to variable t
       ?       Unique
      #        Length
     =         Equal to
 (#t)          The length of t
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>23</s> 18 bytes

```julia
~x=allunique("$x")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CNjEnpzQvs7A0VUNJpUJJ879DYnFxalGJQp2Jhbm5hamFiYKtrUJaYk5xKhdcytDc2MDCxNQSJFVSVJr6HwA)

-5 bytes thanks to MarcMush: replace `digits(x)` with `"$x"`

Comment: -5 bytes: `allunique("$x")`

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
dDZUA=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLUlyiQh1tIRyo2IIVhubGBhYmppYQPgA)

##### Explanation

```python
dDZUA=  # Implicit input
dD      # Cast to digits and duplicate
  ZU    # Uniquify this list
    A=  # Are they equal?
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 47 bytes

```
=LET(a,ROW(1:10)-1,COUNT(SEARCH(a&"*"&a,A1))=0)
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Comment: This could be 43 bytes using `=ROWS(UNIQUE(MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)))=LEN(A1)+1` perhaps. Unless the input is 1048576 characters long =)

Comment: @JvdV Excellent construction!

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
(\s->s==[x|x<-s,y<-s,x==y]).show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyOmWNeu2NY2uqKmwka3WKcSRFTY2lbGauoVZ@SX/89NzMxTsFUoKMrMK1FQUchNLFBIU4g2sTA3tzC1MNFRMDQ3NrAwMbWM/f8vOS0nMb34v25yQQEA)

Repeats each character once per each character that equals it, and checks that this gives the original digits string.

Answer (score 0):

### C 151

Bytes = 181 or 151 without newline chars.
Program keeps a tally of digits and exits if greater than 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i,j[10],r;
int main()
{
scanf("%d",&i);
do{
r=i%10;
j[r]++;
if(j[r]>1){printf("false");return 0;}
i/=10;
}while(i);
printf("true");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# 72 characters**

```
var a=i.ToString().ToCharArray();
return a.Distinct().Count()==a.Count();
```

Comment: ".ToCharArray()" is unnecessary since there's [String.Distinct.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.distinct(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I think that not including the required `using System.Linq;` in your character count is cheating a bit. @helix That's `Enumerable.Distinct`, not `String.Distinct`. MSDN is a bit confusing by showing extension methods too. But indeed, `ToCharArray()` is not necessary.

Comment: you could also do `i+""` instead of `i.ToString()`. But this question is asking for a function, you just gave 2 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 44

```
f(n)=(d=digits(n);length(Set(d))==length(d))
```

Comment: This doesn't work - it only returns true if n is one digit long, as length(Set(d))=1 for any integer. For the same approach idea, perhaps use `unique(d)==d`?

Comment: ```julia> f(123456)
true

julia> f(1234566)
false
``` It seems to work. ```julia> length(Set(1,2))
2``` Perhaps the definition of `length(x::Set)` changed recently? I'm running 0.3 prerelease.

Comment: That might make a difference - I'm running 0.2.1. I get length(Set(1,2))=2, but length(Set([1,2]))=1.

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 109

```
def f(n) as bool
    l=0
    m=n.toString
    for i in m,for j in m,if i==j,l+=1
    return if(l>m.length,false,true)
```

Makes me wish that LINQ would work properly in Cobra.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP - <s>44</s> 33

```php
var_dump(max(count_chars($n))<2);
```

Or Proper function 42 Characters

```php
function(){return max(count_chars($n))<2;}
```

UPDATE : Thanks for @scrblnrd3 pointed out for shorter solution.

Comment: You could cut out a few chars by doing `<2` instead of the ternary operator

Comment: <2 in PHP, DO you have some reference page, how it used in php as I never seen this.

Comment: I mean you could use `var_dump(max(count_chars($n))<2);` instead

Comment: `<?=max(count_chars($argn))<2);` 30+1 bytes: run as pipe with `-F`, prints `1` for true, nothing for false

Answer (score 0):

**C# <strike>72</strike> <strike>69</strike> 67 characters (no libraries needed)**

```
for(;d>0;d/=10)for(int f=d/10;f>0;f/=10)if(d%10==f%10) return true;
```

Ungolfed:

```
for (; d > 0; d /= 10)
    for (int f = d / 10; f > 0; f /= 10) 
        if (d % 10 == f % 10) 
            return true;
```

I'm just using simple maths here.(i.e. number 1231):

- Take the last digit (1)
- Iterate through the quotient (123)
- If the number is equal to our digit (1), then return true
- 3 == 1, 2 == 1, 1 == 1 - found it!

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby(47 characters)**

```
->(x){x.to_s.chars.sort.uniq.size==x.to_s.size}
```

Example usage

```
->(x){x.to_s.chars.sort.uniq.size==x.to_s.size}[10]
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia - <del>29</del> 28

```
f(n)=unique("$n")=="$n".data
```

Old version:

```
f(n)=join(unique("$n"))=="$n"
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# (44 - 64)**

Func

As a lambda (44):

```
y=>!(y+"").GroupBy(x=>x).Any(x=>x.Count()>1)
```

alt lambda (also 44):

```
y=>(y+"").GroupBy(x=>x).All(x=>x.Count()==1)
```

As a Func (63):

```
Func<int, bool> f=y=>(y+"").GroupBy(x=>x).All(x=>x.Count()==1);
```

As a method (64):

```
bool f(int y){return (y+"").GroupBy(x=>x).All(x=>x.Count()==1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>COBOL 66 with Object Cobol extensions</s>

### Microfocus Cobol (<s>721</s> <s>659</s> 592)

```
       method-id u.
       local-storage section.
       77  i pic s9(9) comp.
       77  c pic 9 occurs 10 value 0.
       77  g pic 9.
       01  s pic 9(9).
       01  t redefines s pic 9 occurs 9.
       linkage section.
       77  n pic s9(9) comp.
       77  d pic x.
       88  f value is 'y'.
       procedure division using by value n returning d.
           move n to s. move 'n' to d. perform p varying i from 1 by 1 until i greater than 9 or f. goback.
       p.  move t (i) to g. if c (g) is not zero then move 'y' to d. add 1 to c (g).
       end method.
```

Hmmm, I think I should go back to pitch & putt :(

EDIT: OMGZ I CAN USE LOWER CASE!!!

Answer (score 0):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 100

*not included the unnecessary linefeed.*

```
{a>[>>]}>>,10-[38-[-&a+[<<]>]&a>[[-]3<[-<<]<+2>&a>]
+3<[-<<]>,10-]<+<([-]>-|"false"[-])>(-|"true"[-])
```

Usage:

```
%> beef ebf.bf < unqiue.ebf > unqiue.bf
%> echo 48778584 | beef unique.bf 
-> false
%> echo 17308459 | beef unique.bf 
-> true
```

Answer (score 0):

### VBA (145)

```vb
Function jkl(f As String) As Boolean
For i = 1 To Len(f)
jkl = InStr(1, f, Left(Mid(f, i), 1)) <> i
If jkl = True Then Exit Function
Next
End Function
```

Calling the function and output with **opposite** of the result:

```vb
Sub jj()
Dim f As String
f = "1234256789"
MsgBox Not (jkl(f))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### C - 62

```c
int m[10];f(int a){while(m[a%10]++?0:a/=10);return m[a%10]<2;}
```

I've included the count of the globally declared array (which ensures initialisation to 0).

As a bonus, here is a much shorter technically correct answer:

```c
f(int a){return 1}
```

The question does not state that non-unique digits should return false.  Therefore I claim the current lead for C code with 18 characters, although I expect to be beaten by a scripting language with an answer like:

```c
1
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf.  I think the OP states quite clearly that a number with duplicate digits should return false.  Perhaps you could explain why you think differently?  And explain how an undefined function performs the requested task, and how a singly character can do so in any scripting language.

Comment: @David Wilkins One of the examples returns false; the actual OP just states that unique digits should return true, which the C program I added in jest certainly does.

Comment: Also, if I knew golfscript, for example, I would have written a function returning true in that rather than describing an unspecified "scripting language"

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 74 Chars

```
<?php $a=str_split($argv[1]);var_dump(count($a)==count(array_unique($a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

### VB.NET - <s>189</s> 184

```vb
Function U(I As Integer) As Boolean
    U = True
    Dim D(9)
    Dim S = I.ToString
    For Each E As Char In S
        If IsNumeric(E) Then If D(Val(E)) + 1 > 1 Then U = False Else D(Val(E)) += 1
    Next
End Function
```

First code-golf attempt. I'm aware it's an unsuitable language and poor result, but I wanted to try.

Comment: I counted 189 characters even without necessary whitespace. Please be aware that, unless explicitly stated in the question, we usually count necessary whitespaces in answers. However, you can reduce your source size by removing unnecessary whitespaces (spaces around assignment operators, indentations etc) and using one-character identifier names, e.g. `U` instead of `Unique`, `i` instead of `IA` etc. Also, I cannot test it now but I think you can skip the type definitions of your variables/function (i.e. using only `Dim D(9),i()=I.ToString.ToCharArray`)

Comment: So your first line may become something like `Function U(I)`. Your function can then return integers 0 and 1 instead of false/true. Then your second line can be changed to `U=1` and your `Return False` can be changed to `U=0`. Finally, I'm not sure whether it works but perhaps making `IA` a string instead of a char array can save you a lot of bytes.

Comment: I used an online tool out of laziness, I may have to write a character-counting function instead. Do you count line returns and tabs as characters?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 religiously enforces spacing and indentation, even correcting it before beginning a debug - I don't see a way I can cut them out.

Comment: Also, how do I count bytes in code? Sorry, I looked in Meta and the Help Centre but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Online tools should be sufficient, and [this](http://www.lettercount.com/) seems to be giving a correct count. As for automatic spacing and indentation, Visual Studio should have some settings that allows you to turn it off ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5493003)). Line returns and tabs all count as one each.

Comment: Thank you for the character counter link, though the tool calculates 219 characters for the current code, which is off your initial count. Do line returns and tabs make up one byte, or character?

Comment: @Ace, what did you use to highlight the syntax?

Comment: Click on "edit" to see what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure - (42 - 52)

As a named function (52):

```
(defn f[i](let[s(str i)](=(count s)(count(set s)))))
```

As an anonymous function (42):

```
#(let[s(str %)](=(count s)(count(set s))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala

Cheating with library functions (29/12 characters):

```
def t(i:String)=i==i.distinct
```

Scala version of the GolfScript version (36/19 characters):

```
def t(i:String)=i.intersect(i).size>0
```

Doing the counting work manually (91/74 characters):

```
def t(i:String)=(Map.empty[Char,Int]/:i)((m,c)=>m+(c->(m.getOrElse(c,0)+1))).forall(_._2<2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell (41)

```
import Data.List
f x=show x==nub(show x)
```

About 23 characters shorter than the other Haskell answer and a fair bit more intuitive I think.  Basically the same process but using Haskell's built-in list functions is much easier and shorter.

Comment: I don't think you're required to count the last newline.

Answer (score 0):

**F# - 82**

```
let f i =
    let s = i.ToString() 
    s |> Set.ofSeq|> Seq.length = s.Length;;
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++ 82

this code is at least legitimate

```
int a(uint32_t i,uint32_t r=0,uint32_t h=0)
{return i?r&h?0:a(i/10,r|h,1<<i%10):1;}        // thanks to DreamWarrior
```

## C 47

this works if you compile it in debug mode or provide two more arguments set to 0

```
a(i,r,h){return i?r&h?0:a(i/10,r|h,1<<i%10):1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regular Expression 17 bytes**

```
^(?:(.)(?!.*\1))*$
```

Original expression taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870549.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 23

```
#(=(distinct x)(seq x))
```

Usage: `(#(=(distinct x)(seq x)) "23563462464543")`

Answer (score 0):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), 13 bytes

This is a late post, but...

```
(k&{1k1.|0})0
```

Invokation with -I , which is actually for string parameters.

The long form:

```
while    # while we are still consuming characters from the stack
  setSP  # pop the next stack-id from the stack.  It's the ord of the digit
  stackSz  # test for empty stack
  if
    digit1 setSP  # goto stack #1, and push the true indicator on
    digit1
    retSub        # and halt
  else
    digit0    # mark the stack as having been visited
  endif
endwhile
digit0    # push the false indicator if we got this far
```

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog, 49 bytes

**Code:**

```
p(N):-number_codes(N,L),sort(L,S),msort(L,T),S=T.
```

**Explained:**

```
p(N):-number_codes(N,L), % Convert int to list (of charcodes)
      sort(L,S),         % Sort list and remove duplicates
      msort(L,T),        % Sort list and keep duplicates
      S=T.               % Check if lists are equal
```

**Example:**

```
p(48778584).
false

p(17308459).
true
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ÙQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8MzA//8NjYxNTM3MLSwNDAE)

-1 thanks to Kaldo

---

```
{   # Sort.
 ¥  # Consecutive differences.
  P # Product.
```

---

Works on negatives, though OP never specified...

Comment: ÙQ for 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 45 bytes

```
n~(d=1;rdc{norm{n}sort<}$a~b~(d=d*a!b;b);d)
```

A (probably golfable) approach, which looks for duplicate characters. Instead of a costly `cast.string`, I use `norm`, which applies Unicode normalization, which is a no-op here. I use `rdc` as an expensive hack to iterate over pairs. The most important part of the solution is `d=d*a!b` (I use `d=d*...` rather than `d*=...` since `*=` requires whitespace to prevent ambiguity), which multiplies `d` (initially `1`) by `a!b`, which after being cast to  an int will be `1` only if `a` and `b` aren't equal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 bytes

```
U=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi0JtlxQnJRdDuQtWGJobG1iYmFpC-AA)

##### Explanation

```python
U=  # Implicit input
U   # Uniquify the input
 =  # Does it equal the input?
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 142 bytes

This `function` requires a processor compliant with Extended Pascal, ISO standard 10206.
In particular the `card` function must be available.

```pascal
function f(x:integer):Boolean;var d:set of 0..9;w:integer;begin d:=[];w:=0;repeat d:=d+[x mod 10];x:=x div 10;w:=w+1 until x=0;f:=w=card(d)end
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
    type
        { This will permit a proper `function` domain restriction. }
        integerNonNegative = 0..maxInt;
    
    { Returns `true` if `x` as decimal number contains no duplicate digits. }
    function hasUniqueDecimalDigits(x: integerNonNegative): Boolean;
        var
            { The decimal digits that appear in `x`. }
            digits: set of 0‥9 value [];
            { The total width of a decimal representation of `x`. }
            width:  integer    value 0;
        begin
            { If there are as many distinct decimal `digits` as
              the total `width` of the decimal number,
              we can tell that no digit appears twice. }
            repeat
            begin
                digits ≔ digits + [x mod 10];
                x      ≔ x div 10;
                width  ≔ width + 1;
            end
            until x = 0;
            { `card` returns the cardinalty of a set,
              that is the number of members in a set. }
            hasUniqueDecimalDigits ≔ card(digits) = width;
        end;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 355 bytes

```
          1-}  1-}  1-}  1-}  1-}  1-}  1-}  1-}  1-}  1-}
>>vv<">>~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;~>>?;}
^ ;<1@>]3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!3 >>!
,{>">"   >#v0 >#v0 >#v0 >#v0 >#v0 >#v0 >#v0 >#v0 >#v0 >#v0
.10|>#>>"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#"@^>#]
_<<<<%10>=0 1>=1 1>=2 1>=3 1>=4 1>=5 1>=6 1>=7 1>=8 1>=9 1
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#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)

I don't believe that this was the more optimal solution in convey, but it's cool to see it running at least (You can watch all the process in the "Try it online" link):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

## Perl, 63ish

```
$ echo 48778584| perl -F// -alpe '$"="";$_= 0<"@{[map {$a{$_}++} @F]}"?"false":"true"'
false
$ echo 17308459| perl -F// -alpe '$"="";$_= 0<"@{[map {$a{$_}++} @F]}"?"false":"true"'
true
```