# Are all three integers distinct?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

You will be given 3 integers as input. The inputs may or may not be
 different from each other. 
You have to output 1 if all three inputs
 are different from each other, 
and 0 if any input is repeated more
 than once.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your code as short as possible!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Nice first challenge. We are quite strict about objective winning criteria on this site. [tag:code-golf] seems to be the obvious choice here, so I will add that to your post. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Some test cases would be nice.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting all answers should at least explain why...

Comment: @Adám I think a more accurate title would be _Are all three integers distinct?_

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: My dupe-vote is  a hammer, but [Possible duplicate of "_Determine if all decimal digits are unique_"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28359/determine-if-all-decimal-digits-are-unique/) Slightly different, but most answers can still be ported.

Comment: @Adám According to the meta consensus, we should tell the OP to add the winning criteria themself.

Comment: its not a duplicate, the small amount of input yields to different solutions. id wager if you asked this to electrical engineers youd get a whole different approach to the answer (primarily due to the small number of inputs).. i realize the golfing languages all have de-dup but there is still something to be said for the 'normal' languages and what people's backgrounds are.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```python
lambda*a:len({*a})>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSvRKic1T6NaK7FW087of0FRZl6JRpqGoY6RjrGmJhcy3wiJb6xjDJL/DwA)

Comment: OP asked for 1 vs. 0, so maybe you need one more byte: `lambda*a:len({*a})//3`

Comment: @tsh in Python `1 == True`, I think there's a meta post about it somewhere

Comment: @tsh - [relevant meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/53748) "if it quacks like a number, it's a number" - in Python: `False * True` is `0`; `False + True` is `1`; etc...

Comment: From the relevant meta: "this does not apply to challenges where an exact string output is required", so I'm not sure what really applies here.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 7 bytes

```perl6
*.Set>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfSy84tcTO6L81V3FipYKSSryCrZ1CtUKahkq8pkKtkkJafhGXhomOgqWOgqGmDpeGqY6CkY6CKYhpCBTSUTADMS10FIBqTEBMYx0FENK0/g8A)

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 13 bytes

A different solution to @Kirill by using [`mad()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/mad.html) for an unintended purpose!

```r
mad(scan())>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsIwEEX3PcWAmwyMwVSKCta7hHQiATuBJnUjPXtsKpW/eXwebyoH4HF@2RzkCclZUQhBUhgYLPhZXA5RCHycIHPaLBflzRJYHDe@3x2ltcZPLdyP/w/ddpfRDuoXx8epLI1Xhlo64wrtDoY66ipcaF2FGxm6YvkC)

Comment: Well input is not specified at all, so IMO accepting 3 values as input means we can accept a vector

Comment: R almost competing with golf languages ! :D

Comment: I believe Gauss invented `mad` exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 22 bytes

If we can output boolean values then the last 2 bytes can be removed.

```
a=>new Set(a).size>2&1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i4vtVwhOLVEI1FTrzizKtXOSM3wf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RjRXtKGOkY5xrA6IAWRCGEY6hjARECNWLzexQCNNU/M/AA)

For the same byte count, this works on arrays of any size but assumes the input will never contain a `0` and output is a boolean.

```
a=>!a[new Set(a).size]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k4xMTovtVwhOLVEI1FTrzizKjX2f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RppGtKGOkY5xrKbmfwA)

Comment: Assuming that we can take the input as an array and return a Boolean: `a=>new Set(a).size>2`

Comment: @Arnauld, yeah I had that too but as it stands the spec won't allow it - will be updating if the spec changes, though.

Comment: Oh, wait. I can just tack on `&1` for 22 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```r
all(table(scan())<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv/YoFL1lYA4kUFerHxLiRQNxAm/YifntsKpW5PIbHzFgPwK85uRLlCZN3ohCiTPHB4CDM4kvMQhDyCIWnzfJZFpbI4rkLt91RWmt8t4Xh@O/Qb3V1Kani7onV7wIHi/XTBWXI0glXsDsY6qlvcKY1Da5k6IL1Cw)

Returns a boolean, but as folks have already discussed on the [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171616/78274), this should be OK.

Thanks to digEmAll for saving 2 bytes.

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv/YoFL1lYA4kUFerHxLiRQNxAm/YifntsKpW5PIbHzFgPwK85uRLlCZN3ohCiTPHB4CDM4kvMQhDyCIWnzfJZFpbI4rkLt91RWmt8t4Xh@O/Qb3V1Kani7onV7wIHi/XTBWXI0glXsDsY6qlvcKY1Da5k6IL1Cw "R – Try It Online") porting the [R solution to a very similar question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28418/41725)

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsIwEEX3PcWAmwyMgVSKCnqYMJ1IwE6gSd2IZ49NpfI3j8/jzfUAMi1PX6I@ILNXgxA1x1HAQ1iUS0xKENIMRfJmcdKXaBRl6cJ9d4y1Ft@tcDv@P@TtrpMfzS@O9dMF46inE67Q7@BooKHBmdY1uJKjC9Yv "R – Try It Online") - if you are allowed to have any number > 0 as truthey. Otherwise, append `>0` for `TRUE/FALSE` output in 13 bytes.

Comment: Wow, didn't even know about this function. I'd suggest you post it separately (edit and revive your deleted answer), but I think you have to stick with 13 bytes - while T/F indeed acts like 1/0, 1.48 doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```ruby
->a{1-(a<=>a|a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6x2lBXI9HG1i6xJlGz9n9BaUmxQlp0tKGOkY5xbCwXgm@MxgfC2Nj/AA)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xWjFRrzQvs1Cx9n@BQlp0tKGOkY5xbCwXlGOMzAHC2Nj/AA "Ruby – Try It Online") with `uniq!`

Comment: Boolean and Integer are different types in Ruby.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't read the challenge closely enough, and assumed a truthy/falsey output would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>55</s> 25 bytes

*-29 thanks to Jo King*

```
O@O1u|@O@II-!/;I-!/;u^?-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/fwd@wtMbB38HTU1dR3xpMlMbZ6xb8/2@oYKRgBAA)

It should be possible to golf off quite a few bytes.

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/19Pz9/fwcHQX9/TU1dR3xpMlOrF2esW/P9vqGCkYAwA "Cubix – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to shave off 1 more byte to arrive at 25 bytes in total

Comment: I think you might be missing a `@` in place of the `.` in the 9th spot.  Makes it do some funky things for 1 2 2.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÙQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MzA//@jjXWMdUxiAQ) or [verify some more cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q5nl4gr2SwqO2SQpK9v8Pzwz8r/M/2ljHWMcklivaUMdIxxhI65rqmOoYGoBEjIx1oBjIM9DRtdAxiAUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù     # Uniquify the (implicit) input
 Q    # Check if it's still equal to the (implicit) input
```

Comment: Using standard truthy/falsy rules for [tag:decision-problem], keeping in mind that `1` is the only truthy value in 05AB1E, `¢P` works as well as an alternative 2-byter.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I'm not sure that's actually currently valid - the question asks for outputs 1 and 0 - `4`, for example, is neither `1` nor `0`, nor does not act like `1` or `0` (like `True` and `False` do in Python). The question should probably ask for Truthy/Falsey but at present it does not.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
Boole[E!=##]&
```

Pure function. Takes three integers as input and returns `0` or `1` as output. I know that this is rather similar to [David G. Stork's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171658), but it exploits `SlotSequence` to shave off a byte (as compared to `Boole@*Unequal`).

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

```
-:~.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F/Xqk7vvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagqGCkYIxjGME4vwHAA)

### Explanation:

Is the argument equal `-:` to itself after removing the duplicates `~.`

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 4 bytes

```
3=#?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/39hW2d5QwUjB@P9/AA)

Does the count of the distinct elements equal 3?

Answer (score 2):

## Japt `-N`, 3 bytes

```
eUâ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ZVXi&input=WzEsMiwzXQotTg==)

---

### Explanation

`Uâ` deduplicates the input and `e` tests if it's equal to the original.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>25</s> 26 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c){a=a-b&&a-c&&b-c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSSdZszrRNlE3SU0tUTdZTS1JN9m69n9mXolCbmJmnoYmVzUXZ0ERkJ@moaSaEpOnpKOQpmGoo2Cko2CsqWmNXdIQnyRQpyF2SROEsbX/AQ)

Comment: Fails on [4,2,3]

Comment: @GB Quite right!

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>27</s> 25 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks @AdmBorkBork*

```
+!(($args|group).Count-3)
```

Test script:

```
$f = {
+!(($args|group).Count-3)
}

&$f 1 2 3
&$f 3 2 1
&$f 2 1 3
&$f 2 2 3
&$f 2 1 1
&$f 2 1 2
```

Explanation:

```
    $args|group           # Group arguments
   (           ).Count    # Count of groups 
  (                   -3) # is 0 if inputed integers are unique
 !                        # operator not converts int to boolean: true if integers are unique
+                         # converts boolean to int: 1 if integers are unique, otherwise 0
```

Comment: 26 bytes -- `+(($args|group).count-eq3)`

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 91 bytes

```
,>,>,[-<-<->>]>>+++++++[>+++++++<-]+<<<<[>]>>[<<<[-<->]<[>]>>->[>.<<<->>-]<+]<+[>>>[>]<-.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUsxCoBADHtQ7YG6lnykdFBBOAQHwffXlMMkQ5qk@7P1@3yPK3MC6WokEIAM@G9MQ4zwKr1MLWPcCkdjxlcNE8rBFWttiMx5WT8)

#### How it works

```
,>,>,                   'read input as A, B, and C
[-<-<->>]>>+            'compute A-C, B-C
++++++[>+++++++<-]+     'prepare output
<<<<[>]>>               'if A-C != 0 && B-C != 0
[
    <<<[-<->]           'compute A-B
    <[>]>>->            'if A-B != 0
    [>.<<<->>-]         'print 1
    <+
]
<+
[                       'else (this else is for both of the if statements, even though they are nested... wierd, I know)
    >>>[>]              
    <-.>                'print 0
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
QƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/w2MT/h9sfNa35/z@aK9pQR0EXiA1idRSUFRJzchRK8zILS1O5og10FAwVdIxidbiiLXUUTIDKLIFssAaoeghQVihKLUhNLElNUcjMK0lNTy0q5orWNTQAmQshQEYAWSAUyxULAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <s>25</s> 2 bytes

```
/=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxCoAwDAXQq/zN/EnSzh5GK0KhNKF6/1h0etMrrd4e0swclw3IjgOFqB2LSIIiEZ95qlMlcRrER@0PJNYt/kPGCw)

-23 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes list as argument.

```apl
∪≡⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHqkedCx91Lfqf9qhtwqPevkd9Uz39H3U1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/pykYKhgpGHNBaEMA)

`∪` does the set of unique elements from the argument

`≡` match

`⊢` the unmodified argument?

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 32 bytes

```
import Data.List
$l|hasDup l=0=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIRLJacmI7HYpbRAIcfWwNbwf3BJIlDeVkFFIdpQx1DHKPb/v@S0nMT04v@6nj7/XSrzEnMzkyGcgJzEkrT8olwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 9, <s>43</s> 27 bytes

*thanks to @Olivier Grégoire*

```
(a,b,c)->a!=b&b!=c&a!=c?1:0
```

Previous attempt:

```
(a)->a[0]==a[1]||a[0]==a[2]||a[1]==a[2]?0:1
```

Comment: Why not count it as 43 bytes

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVDBbsIwDL3vKwwSqJHSinQ3UEE77rAT2qnqIQlJFVZSaFKkCfXbOy/tOrZpB8dPL8/2s4/8yuPj4a2XFXcOXrixcHsAMNarRnOp4KmqXq25tCrw4Qd4oyY6CgQNvBiSJBuUdhjnVlRGgvPcY7rW5gAnHBHtfWNsmRfYqXRk7Pw9SUPWR5wKKkm85bNMLMUsk0tEcsfWq34T9M/osVRNXmAfr5x3kI2dAG7AKKQUHqGj99Qn@4tCFbun0qBifwtZWAkXG8bruokmC8HAerBBJhf7d@fVKalbn5xxYa@j@cJRGALiLb4LO6ehLF8VI2BfIEWgkx/H/ldJyOCqC5fv@g8): `(a,b,c)->a!=b&b!=c&a!=c?1:0`.

Comment: Also, the first code (100 bytes) doesn't compile and uses `==` which is not applicable on `String` without issues [which you encounter here](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z8zryS1KC0xOVXBsbq4JLEkM1mhLD8zRSE3MTNPI7ikKDMvPTo2UbM6uLK4JDVXL7@0RK8AKFiikRhtEGtrmxhtGFtTA2MbgdmGULa9gZWhpnVt7f///w1BEAA) (after compilation fix), and in the second code, [`Set.of` method will throw `IllegalArgumentException` if any duplicate is provided](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#immutable). I'm tempted to -1 for not testing at all.

Comment: @olivier Apologies-it was late and I mixed up a few different ideas in my head. As for Set.of, I was just experimenting with Java 9 kinks and don’t have Java 9 myself. I should’ve read the documentation more carefully, sorry about that. I’ll edit once I get on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 10 bytes

```
`==#Unique
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@z/B1lY5NC@zsDT1v19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajkI0lwIQRBvqKBjpKBjH6kC4BmCuJYxrqaNgoaNgAuNCFBsiyVoi6TU0AOqGEbFcsbH/AQ)

This is a fork of the operator `` `== `` and `Unique`, equivalent to:

```
{ _ == Unique[_] }
```

### Alternatives

`{#_=#Unique[_]}` (15 bytes)

`Any##Same=>Pairs@Sort` (21 bytes)

`` Any@{`=&>_[[0'1,1'2,2'0]]} `` (26 bytes)

`&${not(x=y or y=z or x=z)}` (26 bytes)

`&${x/=y and y/=z and x/=z}` (26 bytes)

`{Any!Same=>Chop&2!_[0'1'1'2'2'0]}` (33 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

-2 bytes by Jo King.

```
:{:{:{=}=}=++0=n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36q2FoxsQVBb21Ajz/r///@6ZQqGcMIYAA)

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/36oaBG1rgVBb28A2z/r///@6ZQqGIMIIRBgDAA "><> – Try It Online")

Comment: I should have definitely caught that, thanks!

Comment: @RushabhMehta Please do not golf other user's posts using other user's golfing suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 21 bytes

```
func[b][b = unique b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85Oik2OknBVqE0L7OwNFUhKfZ/QVFmXolCmkK0oYKRgnEsFwrfKPY/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 39 bytes

```sql
SELECT IIF(a=b OR b=c OR c=a,0,1)FROM s
```

Input is taken as separate columns **a, b, c** from a pre-existing table **s**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Tried a variation using `COUNT DISTINCT` from input taken as separate rows, but that was a couple bytes longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 6 bytes

```
ɠḲQL=3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///kgoc7NgX62Br//29kqmCsYG5uBgA)

From 5 to 6 bytes because this is my first time and I messed up (whoops) fixed it now

```
ɠḲQL=3
^^^^^
||||Is it equal to three?
|||How many unique numbers do we have? (length of unique numbers array)
||Sort By Unique
|Split by Spaces
Read Input
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. Does your code also work for `3 integers`, or is it only functional for three digits?

Comment: @Jonathan Frech Sadly, it only works for three 1 Digit numbers, it does this by sorting the input by unique characters, then testing if the amount of unique characters is the same length as the input. Maybe there is a way to get it to work with any 3 integers, but I think this is a good attempt for me at least!

Comment: The challenge specifies _You will be given 3 integers as input._ which seems to render your answer invalid.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Fixed it now! Was my first time doing this sort of thing so, I'm not the greatest at it.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
s{I
```

Takes input as a list.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%7BI&input=%5B3%2C%201%2C%204%5D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
s{I
 {IQ     Check if the (implicit) input is invariant under deduplication.
s        Cast to int.
```

If we're allowed to treat True and False as 1 and 0 (which they are under the hood in Pyth), we can drop the `s` to get down to 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
READ A,B,C?A-B&&B-C&&C-A
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 11 bytes

```ruby
->a{a==a|a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOtHWNrEmsfZ/QWlJsUJadLShjpGOcWwsF4JvjMYHwtjY/wA)

Assuming we can return a boolean. Which everyone is doing nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
d?∧1|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P8X@UcdywxqD//@jjXVMdUxi/0cBAA)

## short explanation

`d?` **d**eduplcates input an test if still equal to input(**?**)

`∧1` if true return 1

`|0` else return 0

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 67 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a.map((m,i)=>a.map((n,j)=>m==n&i!=j).every(z=>!z)).every(y=>y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i5RLzexQEMjVydTE87J08kCcnJtbfPUMhVtszT1UstSiyo1qmztFKs0YbxKW7tKzf/J@XnF@Tmpejn56RppGtGGOkAYq6nJhSFuhFPcGCT@HwA)

Comment: Sorry, but [J answer is already here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171742/78410) and the code is exactly the same.

Comment: my bad @Bubbler didn't see that coming.

Comment: changed to JS answer

Comment: @Bubbler Duplicate entries are [not disallowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/definite-policy-about-duplicate-answers).

Answer (score 1):

## [q](https://kx.com/download) 14 bytes

```
{x~distinct x}
```

Technically this solution will return '1b' or '0b', which is the way a boolean value is distinguished  from a numeric type, though it retains all arithmetic functionality, and so is in essence a 1 or 0:

```
q)1b +35
36
```

To return 1 or 0 non-boolean you have the below, which takes the byte count to 21

```
{$[x~distinct x;1;0]}
```

Comment: `{1&/0N>':x?x}`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 38 bytes

```
echo(4==count(array_unique($argv)))*1;
```

Called with e.g. `php codegolf.php 2 3 4`. $argv always contains the filename of the script, hence 3 unique numbers make 4 elements.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
≠
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4omgIiwiIiwiMSwxLDFcbjIsMywxXG4zLDMsMSJd)

Easy peasy

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>18</s> 11 bytes

```julia
~x=x==x∪x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CtsLWtuJRx6qK/w6JxcWpRSWcinXRhjpGOkaxXFARhbpoAx1DkACXQ3FGfjmQb6JjqmMWi8I1RXANdIAw9j8A)

-7 bytes (!!) thanks to MarcMush: replace `length(x∪x)>2` with `x==x∪x`

Comment: I think `x∪x==x` works

Answer (score 0):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 17 bytes

```
..i..
.MiC.
}u)3=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X08vU0@PS88301mPq7ZU09j2/39DLiMuYwA)

#### How it works

Excluding the mandatory triangular padding, we're left with:

```
iMiC}u)3=
```

Which can minimally be explained as: Push all STDIN as an array of strings (representing each line of  input), count the occurrences of all of STDIN's elements in itself (which, in case all are distinct, should yield **[1, 1, 1]**), sum, then check whether the sum is equal to **3**. There are 2 tricks here (which together save no less than 14 bytes):

- Using `i` and treating the inputs as strings rather than integers – which is quite uncommon, as `)IE` is frequently used instead, taking input as a list.
- Instead of checking whether they all are equal to **1** and then taking the product – or equivalently, taking the product and checking whether it is equal to **1** – this takes the *sum* and compares it with **3**. Proving the validity of this method is obviously trivial: **[1, 1, 1]** is the only valid way to partition **3** into 3 positive integers summing to it and the contents of this list are always positive, as every element of a collection must occur at least once in it :P.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
≔Ｅ³ＮθＩ¬⊖⌈Ｅθ№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DN7FAw1hHwTOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NTR6FQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMMvv0TDJTW5KDU3Na8kNQWoqyIztzQXrLtQR8E5vxSoEsjI1IQA6///jbiMuUz@65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. 5 bytes could be saved by using a slightly non-standard input format `[[x, y, z]]`. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ³Ｎθ
```

Input 3 numbers and make a list.

```
Ｉ¬⊖⌈Ｅθ№θι
```

Count the number of occurrences of each number in the list. Take the maximum, subtract 1, take the logical not, then cast to string for implicit print.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 30 bytes

```php
<?=array_unique($argv)==$argv;
```

takes input from command line arguments; prints `1` for truthy, empty string for falsy

Answer (score 0):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 25 bytes

```
$-<*\\\!!@
::*<&&&
-$$>
$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/X0XXRismJkZR0YHLykrLRk1NjUtXRcWOS@X/f2MFIwXD/7opAA)

Given integers `a,b,c`, evaluates `!!((c-b)*(b-a)*(c-a))`

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>50</strike> 41 bytes

**-9 bytes thanks to GB !**

```c
m(int*a){a=*a==a[2]^*a==*++a^*a==*++a^1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/rCoMgFP7vU0gQaDroAmNg7kWcG1JrGNRG81/47E7bpdx34HjOdwFPs7s1jXMD0qPJFJ4VzxTnSpTyHIaMELUOBbPO@@Cg9IjwDKBH2M31aS6tMkrspagk5PCtBcwFLWllaUyUWyKnvmKHry1xoEUeM2EP1MJYtjzdfQpnQM1zBnW9940QvH7lq/dB7@vKt0gPeEze0aEkbWFCN4dpKXqJ2c9rwX@CH2HankafGtA2hz8pC4AF7gU)

No built-in sets in C, and iterating is too long, but at least i can shave off a few bytes by taking advantage of the fact that `*a == a[0]` ...

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##XU/rCoMgFP7vU0gQaDroAmNg7kWcG1JrGNRG81/47E7bpdx34HjOdwFPs7s1jXMD0qPJFJ4VzxTnSpTyHIaMELUOBbPO@@Cg9IjwDKBH2M31aS6tMkrspagk5PCtBcwFLWllaUyUWyKnvmKHry1xoEUeM2EP1MJYtjzdfQpnQM1zBnW9940QvH7lq/dB7@vKt0gPeEze0aEkbWFCN4dpKXqJ2c9rwX@CH2HankafGtA2hz8pC4AF7gU)

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about incrementing the pointer but couldn't figure out how to make it as short !

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT** **37 Bytes**

```
Set(Array(readLine()!)).count==3 ?1:0
```

Comment: Your current answer is a snippet; either put a wrapper around it or call your language _Swift REPL_.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```julia
f(x...)=length(Set(x))>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jQk9PT9M2JzUvvSRDIzi1RKNCU9PO6L9DcUZ@uUKahqEOEGpyIXONkLlGOsYwbklRaao2iPgPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 12 bytes

```
a->#Set(a)>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P1HXTjk4tUQjUdPO6H9iQUFOpUaigq6dQkFRZh5QVEEJxFFSSAMq0NRRiI421FEw0lEwjgWygUwQD8E0jI3V/A8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ä▼Z
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=841f5a&i=[1,2,3]%0A[1,2,2]%0A[3,3,3]%0A[-5,5,7]%0A[1,2,1]&m=2)

**Explanation**

```
ux=         #Full program, unpacked, implicit input as array
u           #Keep only unique elements in array, maintaining first order of appearance
 x=         #Copy original input onto stack, is it equal to unique-ified array.
```

Short and sweet. Wish Stax would implicitly check against "X" register if there was nothing to check against, but it works out regardless.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 26 bytes

```
g a b c=and$map(==)[a,b,c]
```

Comment: I don't think this works, can you provide an example on how your function is used?

Answer (score 0):

## [Math++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), <s>40</s> 29 bytes

```
?>a
?>b
?>c
(a-b)&(b-c)&(a-c)
```

Comment: I think the non-competing rule is a [thing of the past](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges).

Comment: Also, could you provide an implementation link for _Math++_?

Comment: @JonathanFrech OK, I just added a link to the esolang page; the article includes a link to the reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 38 bytes

```lua
x,y,z=...print(x~=y and x~=z and y~=z)
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/QqdSp8pWT0@voCgzr0Sjos62UiExL0UByKgCMyqBDM3///8b/Tf@bwgA)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for [the case when `y==z`](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/QqdSp8pWT0@voCgzr0Sjos62UiExL0UByKjS/P//v/F/w/@GAA) (returns true, should be false). You'll need to add a third test to check for that possibility.

Comment: Opposed to equality, inequality is not transitive, so \$x\neq y\neq z\$ does not imply \$x\neq z\$.

Comment: Your answer in its current form is invalid. Please either fix or delete it.

Comment: Thank you guys, I really didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 32 bytes

```c
f(a,b,c){return a!=b&b!=a&a!=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/dasIwFAfw@z7F0TFJ4WykjaWRzo29hzdp0m4Bl40ar8Rn705UitRDDod88Ms/sS92b8LX@OSD3R9dB2@H6Pzv6/d75kOEXqRuMPX20m3eXE5@jA8iP2V/A616sfwcOqgQNIIJDtbg/CHSnfEDnt0uLLEXFWpc58TvicJUidQMUaiwnhNKqa6kYlNozImeUjRDNKXoOakRyivZMKTGEjdzUkzf50hB3y8kE3N7mWRjFD4QiakSKRgiUT6SckpRDCkpRSUydPE4BJBNdh57YbBFm59um2axbVftYmtWNLPNeRz/AQ)

Comment: The integers `0, 1, 2` are distinct, yet `0&... = 0`.

Comment: `f(a,b,c){return a-b&&b-a&&a-c;}`

Comment: `b-a`=>`b-c` mistake from your code

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, <strike>25 24 28 27</strike> 23 bytes

Using bitwise, comparison and logical operators [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCoAgAETRq9QmFKbIIqyF3UVNoxCNjK5vQm4@w2NO@cqo7@N6Wh82k6xIREJBU7HKWqgmRzcqJ@ngY3Cmc2EnlnBwMIrKEoYBY1l9MY4Zy2/5NmWl6QM)

(*4 bytes saved courtesy of Jonathan Frech*)

```
(a,b,c)=>a!=b&a!=c&b!=c
```

Comment: You can pull the `1^` inside the parentheses, changing `==` to `!=` and `|` to `&` and then remove said parentheses to save four bytes.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Updated

Answer (score 0):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), <s>85</s> 77 bytes

```
rEeEREeErrEEEEEeRrEeErrEEEEEerEEEEEEERerEEEEEerRrEEEEEEeErREEREEEEErEeReeReEE
```

[Try it online!](//soaku.github.io/Pepe/#QR@&0-Q@&0E6.&0@-Sa@F-jC/N) Input is `a,b,c`. Change the "separated by" box to `,` to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <del>29</del> 23 bytes

```rust
|a,b,c|a!=b&&b!=c&&a!=c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6GpUM2lAAQ5qSUKiTk58SmZxSWZecklCrb/axJ1knSSaxIVbZPU1JIUbZPV1IDs5P/WcA0VCrYomjQMdRSMdBQMNSFKCooy80py8hQ1lKprlXQUKrALYzHAWBOotPY/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

```
▀=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtAbb//@jDXWMdIxjAQ)

### Explanation

```
▀    Get unique elements
 =   Check if equal to the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 5 bytes

```
ul3-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/@/NMdYN@////8A)

Edit: fixed from identical -> distinct

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
s<2l{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9jGKKf6//9oQx0jHeNYAA)

Looks like someone already did pyth but I didn't know about the I for testing invariants.

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 17 bytes

Anything XORd with itself yields zero. So. Any language with multiplication and XOR can do this:

```rust
(a^b)*(b^c)*(a^c)
```

Since input specifics were rather vague I chose a liberal interpretation. Or if you want to be more strict, we can define it as a closure (kind of like a lambda function),

24 bytes

```rust
|a,b,c|(a^b)*(b^c)*(a^c)
```

[Try it on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b1237ffb95f375f97f87797f73faaa7a)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
S=U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X@wbej///@jow11gDBWB0wbgWkjHWMgDSTBtDGYjgUA) Takes the three numbers in a list.

Answer (score 0):

## [Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```sh
$(($1-$2&&$2-$3&&$3-$1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYc7DoMwEAX7PcUrVsgutlivm4ir0CBsZCTELwVFlLMbJ8XMaNL4LnV2/oM8lR1DZedYhUPXcRC2FhNW7@u3v8uyZlx5TDhw4uqRdszgA3yC/7vlqggw@lnJoIgkBgkQo/hq2zCL9AA)

Sorry for a boring answer; at first if bashism would work, but I could not get out of POSIXism.

The code above evaluates to a string of either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 28 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 28 bytes.

- Filename: `._._._.e.z.c.c.z1.o.d.a.a0.o`
- Content: enpty.

[Try it online! (with pxem.posixism)](https://tio.run/##1Rr9V9rK8vf8FWNESMAEAmhVjL1eq23Ptdqj7WvfK9YTkkXyDAknCSgq91/vm93NN0j13rbnPlokmZ3ZnZmdj/0YywgG30xvOLIdIsmSIKyu1Hu2Ww8G@AijWzI01ZEX2Ld2MFThPb4roacYN9cQEfkq4n3y7TAkLvSm8GFkkCPj5o64tOHYNokbEBUODhqqIAQkBIWMYRX/gh1A3/MhmLqhcQvE9z1fGA@N4BoajWZTILcjzw/h@OBy//hYPxDC6YjAFQlNz@3DXt0ik7o7dhxo7pU1KJd5OzI1NFxrUXvU3/v9D290sSTFmMoo6ZQ2yaV7@lPbmfEHZSbGlB9P3n6@PP/wSm82Gi0UgTL/5r3y8XPS9en528/H/748OD07Ozz4oGsR0uuTjzAObSdYhx6qex1G1jXq1zQCAmLp/vf98zeX/zo8O397erJTm85EsF2QprIAwPTlAZuA6LX2O/Zq2YHRcwgQc@DBvbEerFszCD3oRSADArCETocEhpmM859HhyHDsWOEBJApNog3CvH5xvOtYOTYIQINxzYCUK6gUrrXamLpN3FW0Sv0t4KtJx@Pjw/evdJ34iFXwSf/JSb2MvGb0PPGvktiPiQkkJgo1ng4nHZwJLsfdlII0G4TMJOntAqyIHOONcrxyLfdsA9rQbfrUtkaq6vV@mwH3juEjjLGr0tuiM/nRKG2aoQ2VVkwII6jilTqWzsEbRHL7ZhlMjEcEFegbzgBEeHhAe5/7OAzQWCGfyvJy3ouNROaEiNahVYLWpvQegHtFrQ3YBv/v4DtbdAaDfxq@G3idwO/CNMQpiFMQ5jWxi/CtU38buEX25vY3sR2dDvsemjYLv5cEZf41CzQmsa9ke9d@cYQ@r43BNe7wekMYXdXqWhBOLD8itAfu2Zoey4YPXQGaRhcpSKByKQEDUTAhk4kjNSQOyhNQomOGEiAExGum4zY7kt2b9zvE1/XRZGBgLqUSfrOOBhIcodBkECXkDhEnT/QXhzbxfjCKSMc7ArRdvWGTNFxdukPbzIdLyARPcOe4dfUI/oO58Nc@VOEmIWYKVGM0QkaCG9DXUkiqNWSuC6KKEcnhX75ChdVYPAsc5Te8hzH8Bu6SQERg1pOOUNj2ovFpiOxxyAko1otYjGB7Ons0QgjdvkcMBjnJsHUG5yBzDhZ9aYTmBDnSDNkdtBzDPda4hMXSWDqeqv58CBt7@pmuWzu6lqLzfjvh6/fntyzyDMKp7rIfsSke11kP@LceKmeuOZZeJJQnUFomNfr4o4o58GBfUdSsI8BX6J/AkIsBqKmHlkht2Nq/yGyQ@Mhz0/EMAcQmL6NQdHr81ffw3iO8WF1FVTBJ4bluc4UA7ARDFluYa5R@XC6f/4u4xj4a4zs0HAkN6skaXNjV3fLZXdX327ILyW31mrKO25Bu@bQypN12UxKLqq4JaOO6cNm/PAiemjHTe0NfIhptpMBMUrg74q@vcl/tjJYSIUBJAPAUJLQNTmdprWi3xf5icUJwODhRPM08smEz9lMyLZK8QP17pelxo5UamCIEGME1ieXPVVeqSHL5TLvUre8MAoUEQm66VfuZ@xvKXZZ5oDZFu6H6UBRkIgAf9bVusxgSQhzUr5ir43itbhmdl1xPcdip6AELjjnusRc5/DkVZ71dMxFI84EZk@YBgVqd7/Bq9MPr97tH5ydvjk8O8xZ4c113go//VFJZ8a@cj2fXFqIj2lpwN3KJUFIfYU7dQkVKxpixF3ShrEzG09E1aDrLXQTjEvYJag366De4ne6Dug46h1mTBApG9peuSl2srSruXUfRNklwuHJMVZyPL6idBazjyZSAOraPSO8Dbk4f9a/frm5nd5dlOr3mR5p5MRmDaV1mLRXPEw3lO2LGpoHiypfbIvHEXy4uNDLneQFyXlg4WTUoDBtQxRsKEhVqZHJndhUSpGyY75w4BEOzHXSFUSW3CRbT4ZQtI69hzLaiiLfo41xpFiLCX/2RSfTaBGH0NXcotZZ8pSMgd2Lc2x5ebbQDKTgLuVL3mss4wdxFU1eytQClFRqJcPwPG/u83hzh/qyUamFD3fzJLFA7Y1ODuoOqzpOSQY2yzx7gd7eqiEddrimYQjItNF5RUZ4Y502usO9RicHKrBQ7A7TGgs3UlfE5WFXlBHjMVY4@/n2HzgDdn4GstpP6VCxUbZe0ZFlUc4OlHjW3YUeYaWUdDFFydl6UAacz2eRPoacnbl4HUEZ68z7BHXtOakv512108lNWiqyPicyZCRiy1C@Tu6K6uUOLg1wD4m7D2LB4ekREhYsNF5dRb0XTeWv9ozLXM/FlcyYPGZIWYlwMZEfNrjStc4PYqSHCez6SVxszHOh/DI22lu7sdGVy9HD7sbWdxWztN8sf7Y7Goe4wQrxKSRXxM@xOMt612O8gDWJ4Up7q@BW82PZwaPDLTbxrGrn5HqyjiiTk6rWqEkpr880zsLgmdy2IHEHV1Vr8lRXN5@XYnJh5kkBFkddFmCD543/A0P75Cmhna9ScFmyS9NTcFdvyh27Vsvr5EZ/ZH2SAeeVZc8xPdeqBzdL2e@LmUMHGuYxX9q415vHJHlBs9vrjJWMeyOkr2mLevCfN0m0PRzNmYdM/Shn9omL@jRcWaSPW02L7UURtRCxir2x5QTb58rVcCQv1dXNd/PZYqV8X1SAG2upHzzJZB8x2ogBHGFhAFog6O0PFFRvFiS97ekrUlGM3RygibP8F6RfhNR8XEV6c05Ht72nKWj6MxU0XaSgvX@GgqZPVNDdz1TQXU@f04@u/zMUdPdEBRn5uLsAI3xetBwQY6T/og3lcI41OvqKzo4lFyd6KWX8QqfYfyXLW0xpuXOczvyZCz8OaSw6/NDmuqx9T8sF6yuaRu1X6Vz5m4wq39vUFwl26Q66ACvu5n@gfCt/U77qr5qI0jMZnWj6sngyaf4UxhljE62K3ed2dKUduCO@p1j2xA5sz122PEJO9Ulzb6K9pIukSbM@0eQd9qjVJ83la6W1/2strf0NLa2lWlpboqX0NDuOXSvF8@ITD3d0vk@CkedatnsFqsFWtT/l3Jgdl3/6gx@Xp3eZ9MInub6JrzD7rjEk@UtMdjGEGuGJiMnBMhJLCex8N3N8KsQdCMIOsOehbVkOoWUHyZUuvc/V2H0uiid4Fij74IISwlgDZYKg0AflIICG1my1NzZfbG1D5UvXrV5UsO3KJyNQ8YFWXiA27mv09iZ2ye6cxKiBX64XLpHZfQDFoFf7FlSYpuq5pFM3u0IFP5kEzi@ZOvTaucJ0GAnWRy5pMQW9la/MKlS35oCY1zjxaAomCQLDp3cQQO8joG87RKB7ML1BWSZ6I6lGiFVBr/Sr6pf@0UVVZts1XYNC4UIBlRxGqGQOldLTP4QjN5LkGeNRdj03JC67y6PsgRHEdyzZXjK1BtRKxJLGVbhg3gCWzRxAMnfRBAR1tVpffEaRv1yoc3qJKzsxzXhPe1/pUN6iEgmcDDmuZcgIEmtigSISn8BNbtEjqJLyDhHthJ/oENkjAt6AtCyEsWMCYfExAMehpwVCcRnFfDriSsg5VfMf605RvujyN3FeJ/RMhR@bsKCaIsbKiRQSYyvaxUX@UGWeLkWli8@59kV3QwWkWREQ06TnQAWEOFh0kmiRMySMGRVhifTC0wUW5mUUHhErLqwoMi9wO0KmqBP0bddwnKnAvUMQ5G@r1K4t4qvF6jeK7aFHRS23uZZwQKZg@ITXx9D2XPPQs@y@jfZiQA8Holnvw9tT2oL/B2E4Cnbq9Ss7HIx7qukN66/fKGkhXT3XnbAaFeYlEHqCy@vrjk723x3q6iX7R9Q71cR/d5rqqZZqqEZD9YTz049nB4d6pfIt60SMUHy4MUExWdbNuRinebSZES9Cou5DHYnXD6CfRWUpOvcslrJZeZckRTj0U5Ligrz9s9eX7/Y/8xK@hweO3Gy0t@QMugLbyZvMr89lMR2Sl/XoIp1UUFztgYUKjBSTcKw9LAoSgDHigUeIB@riCqEx@ytU6xiQ@QtUS/iSGSUuKslIFuIyiGqCVSKOKQIaRrkcwf05@H0iUSaYWW1QTqBNh8jhPyTITAIrI4ESNc3icjX@kUYB9urBCL2DhPaQrI/M0Xh9Etx1wMIsIGf6zEbTdpzkMsM9mur4J5PwIiLDdlD30G5mgGn05B/N5vGEf5Sm1n7R3mpttrcyODR1diW1e7/VnXXlUr2r1ZPWLAdRWDdw2ZEd4t6o0dqLWQZEl608ThsZeEw0y5sTLxulVa@Jy6TeIdP6QCGy6ApfnjbB8egyCOUnFkZGXNemuQe92PAxT2PqHY1DfPVcQlclGEoCsoPv9a/KS16LUKqv4xvvk0NogRkDMpcq1YXYz1DsoXHrEDcxxTkXe5aDpe7FnCvSBY7Co6QuRpGgkjTwIKmLKQQZx3CLEL6gR3CmHuX07DyqEjo@0uMrbhEzDCubsMYIuLrkOuLFHonM0X4jj6Jr2RIazgv2vLCvdPcSKXdhl/IT@@IVHq2H/M6FZ702Zj395CiT73ifp0fnULILJEllEY5VaIoLjli6WhvTqiMoNTtJcWiTC5PaTSTQSl6iLAt8HqM0mpNKK5Y5dbtrnrieL2KhXa3Cm9NPLxNE8Sbs0xVCcRPHWGy18rvFJaqmiBXmKLwVJFqwzb1ggI8OEsrIv0@EYABK8E3RoIarv8b/AA)

### With comments

```
XX.z
# for three times; do push( read integer); done
.a._._._XX.z
# call subroutine
## NOTE. When DOT-e is performed when stack is a,b,c,bottom,
## then subroutine begins with same content of stack
## And when subroutine ends when stack is d,e,f,bottom,
## then previous stack would be d,e,f,a,b,c,bottom
## to continue origimal procedure
## In this program content is empty, so is subroutine
## thus x,y,z,bottom to x,y,z,x,y,z,bottom,
## which duplicates entire stack
.a.eXX.z
# while size < 2 && pop != pop; do
.a.zXX.z
  # dup; dup; while size<2 && pop!=pop; do
  ## this is equal to while stack is empty; do
  .a.c.c.zXX.z
    # push '1'; putc pop; exit
    .a1.o.dXX.z
  # done
  .a.aXX.z
# done
.a.aXX.z
# push '0'; putc pop; (implicity) exit
.a0.oXX.z
.a
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 11 bytes

```
all-unique?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpSrFBQlFpSUllQlJlXomDNxVWtYKhgpGCsUMv1PzEnR7c0L7OwNNX@v95/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
{(#x)=#?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWUK7QtFW2r6jl4kqLNlQwUjCOBTMMYQwjBROYiGEsADAzC5s=)

A little bit more interesting answer in my opinion, but still boring. Takes a list of integers as input.

Explanations:

```
{(#x)=#?x}  Main function. x is input
       ?    Unique (Remove all duplicated elements)
      #     Length
     =      Is it equal to
 (#x)       The length of x itself
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 91 B

This is a complete `program` conforming to ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” and at 91 bytes certainly more readable than [brain****](/a/171856/).

```pascal
program p(input,output);var x,y,z:integer;begin read(x,y,z);write(ord(card([x,y,z])=3))end.
```

The `[x,y,z]` denotes a *set*, thus duplicate values get collapsed.
This means, the set literal `[4, 4, 4]` is identical to `[4]`.
The `card` function returns the number of distinct elements in the set.
Here this will be anything between 1 and 3 inclusive.
We test for equality to 3 (`… = 3`) which evaluates to a Boolean expression (denoted by the built-in constants `false` and `true`) and convert this enumeration value into an `integer` using `ord`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
ĐỤ=Ʃ3=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISHu5fYHltpbPv/f7ShjpGOYSwA)

```
Đ         implicit input; Đuplicate
 Ụ        get Ụnique items
  =       is equal element-wise?
   Ʃ      Ʃum of list (coerce booleans to ints)
    3=    is equal to 3?; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 22 bytes

```
3&/ M \.!-~?-Zn'0+O@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/99YTV/BVyFGT1G3zl43Kk/dQNvfgUvh////hkb/jYyBJAA)

```
3&/ M \                   Reads the three arguments and puts them on the stack
       .!-~?-             Compares the two last arguments, then the first with the last
                          It leaves [0, 0] on the stack if the two numbers are the same
                          Otherwise any other pair of numbers
             Z            Packs the two numbers together [0, 0] yields 0
              n           Logical not, if the pack result is 0 return 1 and any other number returns 0
               '0+O@      Output and bye
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 37 bytes (24×2=48 codels)

```
TAbTlTiTrTtTLDqMmMEuAkAaAqQIBSAMVcRrr
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.space/#eJxdjsEKgzAMhl8l5BwhqW1FX0U9DNeB4DrB7SR797VpvayEfP37J2lOXF73gMM4Mkk_0yi-0hIneM3CCqOZq1HKTKElkSylsivPjsQn9AV5ttdiW4ZePynbvwWkssKR0RXMPBMeYccBm6ZBwm19prtwOkmFY8HhcduOQLjG_fPOHgiYKabyKXoGjSoNQ8tgLmkdOA--qzK1QXtZYHPYKeL3BxypTAY)

Probably not the golfiest that could happen but manipulating the stack order in Piet is a bit of a pain.

#### Pointer Path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 4 bytes

```
..|=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfHR1tqGCkYByrAKaNYmP1qhNqVWOq/@vp1dj@r1UF8WKrMgsU8rT@AwA)

Input is taken as an array of three numbers

## Explanation

```
..|=
 .|  # Setwise OR the input array with itself
.  = # Is it equal to the initial input?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

- `U⁼`: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS0IfNe5ZUpyUXAwVWLA-2tDIWEfBxNRMR8HcwjIWIgwA)
- `ċ⁼`: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS490P2rcs6Q4KbkYKrJgfbShkbGOgompmY6CuYVlLEQYAA)
- `ȯ⁼`: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS0-sf9S4Z0lxUnIxVGTB-mhDI2MdBRNTMx0FcwvLWIgwAA)

##### Explanation

```python
U   # Uniquify the input list
ċ   # Or, take the set union of the input list with itself
ȯ   # Or, take the set intersection of the input list with itself
 ⁼  # Then, check if this new list is equal to the input list
```

Comment: Of all of these, only `U⁼` and `ċ⁼` seem to be valid; the question asks if all are distinct, while you are checking if they aren't all equal, which fails for inputs like `[123, 123, 456]`

Comment: @noodleman oh yeah, thanks for telling me. `ȯ⁼` works as well btw.

Answer (score -1):

**Python 2**

```
def e(a,b,c):return 1 if len(set([a,b,c]))>2 else 0
```

...could be shortened to

```
def e(a,b,c):return len(set([a,b,c]))>2
```

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the task. Your code should check whether all 3 integers are _distinct_ not _identical_.

Comment: what if `a==b` but `a!=c`?

Comment: I'm afraid that is not all. Now it says correctly that 1,1,1 is false (not all distinct) and 1,2,3 is true (all distinct), but for 1,2,2 gives also true, though they are not all distinct.

Comment: Fixed it with a set. Should be working correctly now.

Comment: @Milbrae I think your ternary if is nigh a no-op.

Comment: if the 3 integers are provided in a list: `lambda a:len(set(a))>2`